# Hello world! with limited character repetition

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source, hello-world

In a language of your choice, write a program that *exactly* outputs the characters `Hello world!` followed by a newline. The code:

- should not use any character more than twice (alphanumeric, symbol, whitespace...anything)
- should not use any external resources
- should not use any user input
- should not output anything else

An example of a valid python program:

```
print("He%so world!"%(2*'l'))
```

An example of an invalid python program (the character 'r' is used three times):

```
print("Hel"+chr(108)+'o world!')
```

Winner is whoever has the most votes after 14 days.

EDIT:  A winner has been chosen!  Thanks all for your work on this question!

Comment: Is it allowed to use a letter more than twice in different case? E.g. "RRrr"

Comment: @Boann since I did not specify in the original question, it is allowed (since they are technically different characters).

Comment: What about the repeated letter o in the "valid" python example. There also these:- " ' ( )

Comment: @AdamSpeight what do you mean?  The letter is only used twice, as per the specs.

Comment: @josh The first condition need to be rewritten to be more clearer.

**should not repeat a character more than twice. Eg alphanumeric, symbol, whitespace...anything**

Comment: @AdamSpeight ... which is literally the same.

Comment: @VisioN It isn't literally the same. The original makes it more prominent that it reads as no repetition. Eg only one use of a character is permitted (which it is what it's asking). Whereas in my version the condition is much easier to read, as it doesn't break the condition into two halves.

_comments doesn't preserve the line breaks which makes it impossible to display an example._

Comment: @AdamSpeight: Then make an edit if you feel that strongly about it.

Comment: It seems, it con not be done using **java**?

Comment: @Prizoff I believe so.

Comment: I think you mean a character should not appear more than twice, that is, it should not be repeated more than once.

Comment: I guess [tag:brainfuck] is out of the question...

Comment: **VB.net** (impossible?) Console.WriteLine() As just to output something uses o x 2 e x 3 ( x 1 ) x 1 l x 1 r x 1 **Edit**
Also consider that the minimal about of required ceremony is Module z Sub Main End Sub End Module Also VB doesn't have C#'s escapes sequences \x108 .

Comment: No, it's not doable in Java.  I've been trying to do it for fun.  Impossible to do it with less than two `s` characters.  At best, you have to have a `class` word and a `static` word, which is three.

Comment: Do `include <file>`s count?  I can't do it in C++ unless they don't.

Comment: includes do count.

Comment: You know that you are dealing with ascii values too much when you see any number (in this case, the vote count of 32) and immediately translate into the appropriate character (Space). I guess Befunge just does this to people.

Comment: in your valid example 'l' is used twice!

Comment: @BlueFlame reread the requirements especially the first.

Comment: @BlueFlame It is ok to use a character more than once. You can use 2 of the same characters.

Comment: how the first python program be valid if it uses 2 `o`s, 2 `(`, 2`)`, 2 " (quote), 2' (apostrophe), the spec only says that "should not use any character more than twice (alphanumeric, symbol, whitespace...anything)", not "should not use any character more than twice (alphanumeric) repetitively"

Comment: Should this question be protected? I've seen at least 2 answers that weren't answers.

Comment: In-browser javascript console counter: `function t(s){return [].reduce.call(s,function(n,c){n[c]=1+(n[c]|0);return n},{})}` - usage `t('golfcode')`. Escape backslashes as \\ to avoid getting literals.

Comment: impossible in D unfortunately as to output anything you need to `import std.stdio;` (3*t)

Comment: The valid python also has two `r`!!

Comment: @JeffGohlke Note that you can get a bit farther by substituting an `s` by `\u0073`. You can only substitute one because then you'll run out of `0`s, so you still can't have a working Java program (you also need 3 `t`s and `i`s).

Comment: @Mehdi Read the rules again...

Comment: The rules are ambiguous. Your example `print("He%so world!"%(2*'l'))` uses `'l'` and `o` twice. It also contains multiple `r"'()` characters in the source, if that matters.

Comment: Right. The rules say "should not use any character more than twice (alphanumeric, symbol, whitespace...anything)", so you can have TWO of each character.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc — What are you trying to say ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco misread. I thought it was non repetition, only one character allowed

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## Ruby (1.9+)

Since this is a popularity contest let's try to not use ANY of the characters from 'Hello world!' while still using other characters only a maximum of two times:

```
puts("S\107VsbG8gV29ybGQhCg".unpack(?m))
```

It's 40 chars btw.

## Bash

And this one uses unicode magic.

Notes:

- While the orignal characters appear elsewhere (unlike the ruby example), the printed string contains only non-ascii characters.
- Two from the three spaces are actually tabs, so there are no utf-8 characters that appear more than 2 times
- As binary some of the octets do appear more than 2 times, hopefully that's not against the rules. I'm trying to resolve them though.

Code:

```
echo ' ¡'|iconv -t  asCIi//TRANSLIT
```

For those who don't have a proper font installed it looks like this:

[image: code as image]

Here is the hexdump:

```
00000000  65 63 68 6f 20 27 f0 9d  93 97 f0 9d 90 9e f0 9d  |echo '..........|
00000010  91 99 f0 9d 92 8d f0 9d  93 b8 e2 80 8a f0 9d 93  |................|
00000020  a6 f0 9d 97 88 f0 9d 96  97 f0 9d 96 91 f0 9d 98  |................|
00000030  a5 c2 a1 27 7c 69 63 6f  6e 76 09 2d 74 09 61 73  |...'|iconv.-t.as|
00000040  43 49 69 2f 2f 54 52 41  4e 53 4c 49 54 0a        |CIi//TRANSLIT.|
0000004e
```

You have to run it on a machine where the default charset is utf-8. I tried on an OSX10.8 using iTerm2 with the following environment:

[image: bash running in iTerm2]

## PHP 5.4

This uses zLib: (unfortunately it does uses the characters `e` and `o`)

```
<?=gzuncompress('x▒▒H▒▒▒W(▒/▒IQ▒!qh');
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000  3c 3f 3d 67 7a 75 6e 63  6f 6d 70 72 65 73 73 28  |<?=gzuncompress(|
00000010  27 78 9c f3 48 cd c9 c9  57 28 cf 2f ca 49 51 e4  |'x..H...W(./.IQ.|
00000020  02 00 21 71 04 68 27 29  3b                       |..!q.h');|
00000029
```

## +1

Here is the ruby 2.0 code I used to test for duplicates:

```
d=ARGF.read
p [d.split(//),d.unpack('C*')].map{|x|x.inject(Hash.new(0)){|i,s|i[s]+=1;i}.select{|k,v|v>2}}
```

Comment: While I always appreciate Unicode cleverness, your bash attempt doesn't seem to satisfy the question's specification. "write a program that *exactly* outputs the characters `Hello world!` followed by a newline"

Comment: @FireFly: it does satisfy it. iconv with the target encoding `ascii//translit` will transliterate the unicode characters to basic ascii. And of course echo will add the newline, so this one fits the spec (if we don't consider the similarity of the octets)

Comment: On my system I get `Hello World?` instead of `Hello World!`

Comment: @SztupY oh, you're right, my bad. Very clever, I like it!

Comment: @marinus this unfortunately depends on the iconv version used. I'll clarify the environment and put up a screenshot.

Comment: How many bonus points would you get if your duplicate-checker also conformed to the repeating spec? :-)

Comment: @corsiKa: I've been thinking about this for 15 minutes, but unfortunately I need at least 4 `.`-s (and also need to decrease c,h and r from 3): `ARGF.chars.sort.chunk(&:ord).each{|y|p y}`

Comment: @SztupY I'm not a ruby guy, but what if instead of sorting and chunking, you just counted and spit out the counts? That might cut down on the number of .'s, perhaps replacing them with a () pair if you use a closure? But again, I'm not a ruby guy.

Comment: Your first hexdump has the character `9d` ten times.

Comment: @MrLister '\x9D` is an octet that is part of a single Unicode character. The question did specify repetition of characters, not bytes, so I'd consider this legal. Anyway, he could encode it in UTF-32, in which case going by (32-bit) characters would make it satisfy the rules.

Comment: Congrats on the win, @SztupY!

Comment: The Bash solution has pretty Unicode  ! :-) However, it does not give the exact string wanted by the question. One can correct this with a ``.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco: oh, you are thi first one to discover that I have used an uppercase W :)

Answer (score 62):

You have to use more expressive languages.

## Chinese,  <strike>6  4</strike>   3 chars

```
喂世!
```

Running google translate on this produces  `Hello world!`

(thanks @sreservoir and @Quincunx for the update)

Comment: +1 for rule bending... *"In a language of your choice..."*

Comment: Love it. But how exactly is that a program?

Comment: Actually you can look at it as a program in a google translate language - for Chinese as its sub-language :)

Comment: +1. Nice idea. 世界 = Shì jiè = World. 你好 = nǐ hǎo = Hello. "World, Hello!" translates to "Hello World!". It can be golfed down some more: [`你好世!`](http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD%E4%B8%96!)

Comment: @Tomas Native speaker? Whom are you talking about? I'm no native speaker; the only part of your answer I understood was 你好 (and the fact that "World, Hello!" means "Hello World!"). I used google translate to figure out the other part. My "improvement" came from fiddling around on google translate.

Comment: @Quincunx OK, sorry! I supposed no one else would understand Chinese. You are a real hacker. :) I will delete the irrelevant comment.

Comment: can be golfed down further to `喂世!` at the expense of ... well, nothing more is really being expended.

Comment: @sreservoir wow, thanks! Seems to be more exciting than debugging a classical programming language!! :-)

Comment: Haha, `喂世!` is giving me "Feed the world!" as the first option.

Answer (score 45):

### HQ9+, 1 char

```
H
```

keeping it simple :)

Comment: HQ9+ outputs a comma though ;)

Comment: oh sh.. you're right!

Comment: I'd still keep your answer out...it is a popularity contest after all, rules are for the wind!

Comment: For any challenge like this, HQ9+ should be outlawed just because it's so obvious to begin with.

Comment: @Josh This is one of the rare events where I miss the downvote button on comments. If we throw away rules there is nothing left to justify the contest at all.

Comment: @Howard I feel dirty. I upvoted yours and Josh's comment

Comment: This is what I was about to post. Maybe I should post an answer in H9+, HQ9++, CHIQRSX9+, etc..

Comment: All `print Hello World` questions are actually `who can submit a HQ9+ answer faster` questions.

Comment: What does this output ?

Answer (score 45):

## Vim command (18 keystrokes)

`iHe`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`3al`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`io Wor`<kbd>Right</kbd>`d!`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Doesn't repeat any keystroke more than twice.

It *kinda* violates the "user input" rule since it's still the user that needs to input that sequence, but I suppose if you store it as a macro or an nnoremap beforehand it would count, since you're just running it without explicitly doing any input to make it happen.

It also requires `nocompatible` to be set, which may count as using external resources, so I have provided another variation below:

---

## Vim command (21 keystrokes)

`iHe`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`3al`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`io Wor`<kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>`$ad!`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This variation doesn't require `nocompatible` to be set, although it does work around using <kbd>Esc</kbd> three times by using <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> in its place.

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: you have an 'e' and 3 'E'; 3 'i'

Comment: If you're talking about the characters in `Right`, `Esc`, and `Enter`, they're not literally those characters. Vim deals in keystrokes, which I am deeming equivalent to characters for the purposes of this contest (and the "don't repeat more than twice" rule). I only use the `i` keystroke twice, and the `<Right>` keystroke once. As for `E`, I never use it at all - but I do use `<Esc>` twice and `<Enter>` once.

Comment: Now I'm disappointed that Emacs doesn't have a M-x hello-world command...

Comment: Even if it did, that's three `l`s.

Comment: You should note that you have to `:set nocompatible`.

Comment: Amazing, but myself find using `Right` not very vim-y.

Comment: @jazzpi: Wait, really? I didn't even notice.

Comment: What part requires `set nocompatible`? I found it in my .vimrc, so I think I didn't even notice it wasn't default settings.

Comment: @JoeZ.: The `set nocompatible` makes VIM not act like vi, in that vi didn't actually support movement with the arrow keys but would print A, B, C and D instead of applying the movement.

Comment: I see. If you wanted to do it without `nocompatible`, you'd have to replace `Right` with something like `<C-[>$a`, which increases the keystroke count to 21.

Answer (score 44):

### C, 192 chars

```c
#
#
/*$$@``*/ATION_[]={9.};main(BBCDDEEFFGGHJJKKLLMMPPQQRRSSUUVVWWXXYYZZabbdefgghhjjkkmpqqsstuuvvwxyyzz) {printf("He%clo \
world!%c\
",2^7&!8.&~1|~-1?4|5?0x6C:48:6<3>2>=3<++ATION_[0],'@'^79-5);}
```

Since this isn't golf, I decided to have some fun and try to use every character *exactly* twice (while putting as few as possible in a comment, because that's boring).  I realise that I didn't do terribly well, since my code contains a ton of boring "dead" code too (not in the literal sense, but in the sense of placeholder characters just used in order to fullfil the requirement).  Anyway, this was surprisingly hard (but fun) with the two-character limitation, so unfortunately I couldn't come up with anything more interesting.  It did give me an idea for a new problem though...

(Updated per @ugoren's comment.)

Comment: Creatively impressive.  I like it.

Comment: The slash `\\` ending lines three and four make it a line continuation, not newline.  And line four is terminated by a EOF, making it legal.

Comment: I think you can easily uncomment `.` by using it for fractions. Also you can declare an array and use `[]`.

Comment: @ugoren good call about `.`; I only thought about using it for struct access. <s>As for array declarations, I'm out of `,`s due to the `printf` call, and I'm also out of `;`s, so I'm not sure how I could declare one.</s> Duh, I could replace `ATION_`...

Answer (score 30):

## Piet-- No characters whatsoever!

[image: Hello world in Piet]

Comment: I would consider the codels as "characters".

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann What would you consider to be a unique codel? EG different shapes? colors? sizes? some combination thereof?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart the definition of a unique codel is given in [the specs of the language](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html): it s a block of codel that could be simplified as a single colored pixel.

Comment: @plannapus In that case I don't this challenge is technically possible in Piet. I may come up with something creative though.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart oh it wasn t a criticism of this answer: i love it! This challenge was not a codegolf anyway.

Answer (score 26):

**Perl, 29 characters**

This answer includes x-rated clogs!

```
say"07-8*d<#B+>!"^xRATEDkL0GZ
```

**Perl, 23 characters**

Shorter, but no porno shoes. :-( Same basic idea though...

```
say'0@@lo World!'^"x%,"
```

**Perl, 20 characters**

Boring...

```
say"Hello Wor\x6Cd!"
```

Comment: Um....kinky?  +1 :)

Answer (score 24):

### Powershell, 20

```
"He$('l'*2)o world!"
```

Answer (score 19):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 11 characters

```
丟낆녬닆묬긅덯댦롤긐뤊
```

I saw this beautiful HelloWorld program on [esolang's Hello World program list](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hello_world_program_in_esoteric_languages#Sclipting).

Comment: Whoa! Congratulations, you are the first person ever to post anything about any of my esolangs outside of esolangs.org :) (or at least the first I found out about)

Answer (score 18):

## Scala: *<strike>34</strike>* 29 characters

I'm proud of myself for this one:

```
printf("He%c%co world!\n",108,108)
```

Had a really hard time overcoming duplicate 'l's, 'r's, quotation marks and brackets. Then I discovered the old Java `printf` function, which will happily convert numbers to letters when given the `%c` format specifier.

#### Update

*MrWonderful* did a wonderful thing by pointing out that a whole bunch of characters can be saved by using up my second 'l' manually in the string!

```
printf("Hel%co world!\n",108)
```

Comment: @KCaloux, Since you are allowed up to 2 'l's, wouldn't **printf("Hel%co world\n",108)** at 28 be even better?

Comment: @MrWonderful I think you're absolutely correct! (Also I just realized that I forgot to include the '!')

Comment: From what I understand, this isn't a valid entry, though a good attempt at it. `printf` contains a `r` as does `world`. Same goes for the letter `o` which is used more than once. This is based on my interpretation of the following statement from the OP "An example of an invalid python program (the character 'r' is used three times): `print("Hel"+chr(108)+'o world!')`"

Comment: @JAnderton I had a ruby program parse out my script to make sure there were no characters included more than twice. Read it again. There are 2 rs, not 3. One in "printf" and one in "world". The reason the python one is invalid is because it includes `chr`

Answer (score 17):

### Python 3 [38 bytes]

```
exec('import '+chr(95)*2+"h\x65llo__")
```

I wouldn't consider `import __hello__` as an external resource.

Answer (score 15):

## Perl: 34 characters

```perl
$_="He12o wor3d!
";s{\d}{l}g;print
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1# perl -e '$_="He12o wor3d!
> ";s{\d}{l}g;print'
Hello world!
```

(Not a big deal. Posted just to use at least once in my life `s///` with those fancy delimiters.)

Answer (score 15):

## PHP, 33 chars

I just love how much PHP is forgiving and understanding!

```
<?=Hel.str_rot13("yb jbe").'ld!';
```

Before it was deleted (or if it's still there, I'm totally blind), I saw a comment saying "No brainf*ck? :D". Well, it is pretty much impossible to write a solution in BrainF*ck, as you know. But I managed to code this, just for the lulz.

```
++++++++++[>++++>+++++>++++++>+++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>+++++++++<<<<<<<-]
>>>.+++.--.>++.>+.+++++++.<<<<++++++.>>>>>+++++.+.--.>+++++.<.---.+++++.<<<<-.+
+.<------.------.>>>>>+++++.<----------.<<<<--.>>>>++++++++.--------.+++.
<<<<++.+++++++.+++++.-------.>>>>+++++++.--------.<<<<------.++++++.>++++++++.
```

If you don't have a BF interpreter, the code above just prints the PHP one :P

Comment: I didn't know even a code like this is valid! Php tag isn't closed and string `Hel` isn't surrounded by quotes. Also I've never heard about `str_rot13` before.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt the closing php tag is not required on EOF, and if you put a string without quotes it assumes it is an undeclared constant with the same content as its name and gives a warning

Comment: You have two ls...

Comment: @Manishearth Ooh, you should see the comment thread on the question.

Comment: I commented regarding Brainfuck keeping in mind that it will be completely impossible not to use same characters more than twice :)

Comment: You can avoid the warning (and save the first `.`) by putting the `Hel` before the `<?=`.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann `Hel<?=str_rot13("yb jbe")?>ld!`

Comment: @VisioN I know, I wrote that just for the lulz, as I stated before! :)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I would say that using that is like cheating, since it's not pure PHP anymore.

Answer (score 13):

## [HTML Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/q45Ee/) - 21 characters

```
Hel&#108;o World!<br>
```

Comment: Does that include the trailing newline?

Comment: Doh...missed that requirement!  I'll add a <br> in there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the `<br>` tag actually outputs a `\n` character.

Comment: @netinept :It asked for a newline, not a `\n` so I'd say `<br>` counts

Comment: But the character `r` is repeated in the solution. Did I misinterpret the requirements?

Comment: "l" and "o" too, but each character can be used twice at most.

Answer (score 12):

## Ruby: 27 characters

```ruby
puts [:Hel,'o wor',"d!"]*?l
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1# ruby <<ENDOFSCRIPT
> puts [:Hel,'o wor',"d!"]*?l
> ENDOFSCRIPT
Hello world!
```

## Ruby: 25 characters

(Based on Vache's comment.)

```ruby
puts 'He'+?l*2+"o world!"
```

## Ruby: 23 characters

(Copy of [Danko Durbić](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1308/danko-durbic)'s Powershell [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18725/4198).)

```ruby
puts"He#{?l*2}o world!"
```

Comment: `puts 'He'+'l'*2+'o world!'` is one character shorter!

Comment: But has 6 “'”'s…

Comment: haha I was so focused on letter characters that I never noticed that. never mind!

Comment: @Vache, your comment is actually good. Thank you for it.

Comment: Remove the space after puts and make it 23. -- `puts"He#{?l*2}o world!"`

Comment: Also `puts` can be replaced by `p`. So 20 chars. -- `p"He#{?l*2}o world!"`

Comment: @SampritiPanda, `p` includes quotes in the output. I prefer to keep strictly with the required output format. But you are right, the space is not needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

## C - 43 Characters

```
main(){printf("Hel%co World!%c",'k'+1,10);}
```

### Output

```
Hello World!
```

### Character Counts

```
' ' Count: 1    '!' Count: 1    '"' Count: 2    '%' Count: 2    ''' Count: 2
'(' Count: 2    ')' Count: 2    '+' Count: 1    ',' Count: 2    '0' Count: 1
'1' Count: 2    ';' Count: 1    'H' Count: 1    'W' Count: 1    'a' Count: 1
'c' Count: 2    'd' Count: 1    'e' Count: 1    'f' Count: 1    'i' Count: 2
'k' Count: 1    'l' Count: 2    'm' Count: 1    'n' Count: 2    'o' Count: 2
'p' Count: 1    'r' Count: 2    't' Count: 1    '{' Count: 1    '}' Count: 1
```

Comment: Don't you need `main` etc?

Comment: @FireFly I guess so!  It did say to write a program.

Comment: That's C but not C++.  C++ does not have implicit int (and you can't spare another `i`).

Comment: @BenVoigt Okie dokie!

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript, 66 characters

```
alert('Hel'+window.atob("\x62G8gd29ybGQhCg=="));//rH+in.\x689yQhC;
```

Inspired by FireFly, every character used by this code is used exactly twice.

Comment: I think you are allowed to use some characters just once, and you can drop the comment.

Comment: @JanDvorak - well, sure he could have done it that way - but I think this solution is deserving of an upvote for the sheer bloodymindedness of using each and every character exactly twice. :-)

Comment: +1, but it's easy to use each character exactly twice if you just add gibberish as a comment.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript [37 bytes]

```
alert(atob("SGVsbG8g")+'wor\x6cd!\n')
```

Too primitive isn't it?

Comment: Where’s the newline?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Sorry, forgot it. Now it is in place.

Answer (score 9):

## nginx.conf

```
return  200 "He&#x6clo wo&#x72ld!\n";
```

In action:

```
% curl -6 http://localhost/ | lynx -dump -stdin
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    21  100    21    0     0  20958      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21000

   Hello world!

%
```

Comment: There are 4 spaces in this solution...

Comment: @Josh, actually, there are 5.  But couldn't you consider that two of the first four are tabs, and then the last one is a non-breakable space? :-)

Comment: That works for me!

Comment: @Josh, actually, now that we're using HTML, no more need for `set`.  This only has 3 spaces now, any one of which could be a tab!

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Uses 3×'r' though

Comment: @JoelPurra, nice catch, fixed. :-)

Answer (score 9):

## Emacs Command (15 keystrokes)

```
He<Ctrl-3>l<Left>o wor<End>d!<Enter>
```

If that vim answers is legal then this must be too :)

Joking aside, macro it can become too :)

More nonsense aside, I can probably squeeze some more, but this seems to be good enough for the time being (since it beats vim).

P.S., please ignore all my nonsense (I (rarely, but)use vim too!).

Comment: I still think vim > emacs.

Answer (score 6):

## Befunge 98

```
a"!dlrow ol":'e'Hck,@
```

Here is a version where every character appears twice.

```
bka!e:dw"H@!dlrow  ol":'e'Hbk,a,@
```

Leaves a bunch of junk on the stack.

As a bonus, every single character has something done with it by the IP.

Answer (score 6):

### Malbolge

```
(=<`#9]~6ZY32Vw/.R,+Op(L,+k#Gh&}Cdz@aw=;zyKw%ut4Uqp0/mlejihtfrHcbaC2^W\>Z,XW)UTSL53\HGFjW
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to print `Hello, world.` instead of `Hello world!\n` :(  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/1/D1iZB2TK2ziwq0tgorFxfL0hH279Aw0dHO1vZPUOt1jmlyiGx3Na6qtK7XLW0xCS0sMBAPzcnNSszoyStyCM5KdHZKC48xi5KJyJcMzQk2MfUOMbD3S0r/P9/AA "Malbolge – Try It Online") Impressive, but invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Actually I don't like cheating :P

**Python**

```
print("!dlrow os%eH"[::-1]%('l'*2))
```

Comment: You should specify that it's for python2. In python3 the you get the reversed string as output and then a `TypeError`.

Comment: For use in Py3K argument of print must by enclosed in parenthesises. `print("!dlrow os%eH"[::-1]%('l'*2))` work in both (Python2 and Py3K) versions.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript

```
'He

o world!'n/"l"*
```

Substitutes two newlines (fortunately the third one, needed for the substitution, is provided by the built-in `n`), using both types of string literal to avoid quadruplicate copies of a quote mark. Since `l` is the only character which occurs more than twice in the original string, it's not too hard.

Comment: You forgot the "!".

Comment: @Howard, missed it. Oops.

Comment: The letter o is repeated also

Comment: @AdamSpeight: There is only twice the letter `o`. The rules say that it's not allowed to have a character *more than twice*.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm.

In C, given these rules, we can only have one `#define` (because of `i` and `n`) and at most two function calls OR definitions (`(` and `)`).

I presume there's pretty much only one way to do it (though I'm probably wrong):

```
main(){puts("Hello w\x6fr\154d!");}
```

Comment: You still need to output the trailing newline.  Doing this challenge in C is difficult...

Comment: @Josh I just have to use `puts()` instead of `printf()`.

Comment: But what's wrong with `o` in `world`?

Comment: @VisioN In an old draft of the same code (before I realized how hard it actually was to write such a program) I used another 'o' elsewhere. But this isn't [tag:code-golf], so I guess it doesn't have to be fixed.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure why every answer is displaying a character count.

Answer (score 4):

## XQuery, 19 chars

```
"Hello Wor&#x6C;d!"
```

Answer (score 4):

#### BASH

```
printf 'Hel\x6co world!\n'
```

Cred [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

```
echo $'Hel\x6c\x6f world!'
```

Comment: The first one has 3 “e”'s and 3 “o”'s.

Comment: @manatwork: Gag; thanx ;)

Comment: In Bash you may skip `-e` by using the special `$'…'` syntax: `echo $'Hel\x6c\x6f world!'`.

Answer (score 4):

## C - 46 Characters

`main(){printf("He%clo wor%cd!\x0d",'l',108);}`

Prints out:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: If you're aiming for golf, `main(){printf("He%clo world!%c",108,10);}` should work, and saves you a few chars.

Comment: @FireFly you're right, you'd save me 3 characters.  Your suggestion works perfectly, too.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP

32 Chars

Note how I am not using a character more than twice, since l != L

```
He<?=strtolower("LLO WOR");?>ld!
```

Also note that, despite of Stack Overflow deleting it in the representation, there's a line break after the `!`.

Comment: You are using three spaces, but I guess this can be fixed removing the ones near the PHP tags! :P

Comment: That was fast, although I realized before of reading your comment (from another answer actually)

Comment: Isn't the output "H" supposed to be uppercase?

Comment: Completely true, missed that also ):

Answer (score 3):

### AWK,34

```
BEGIN{printf"Hel%co world!\n",108}
```

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, 21 characters

```
'He'[108]+"lo world!"
```

`108` is the ASCII code for `l`.

First, I push `He` on the stack. Then, `He` gets popped and becomes `Hel`. Then I push `lo world!` on the stack. Now there are two elements on the stack. Because at the end of a GolfScript program, everything of the stack is outputted, this program outputs:

> Hello world!

followed by a newline, because Golfscript always outputs a newline.

Answer (score 3):

## nginx.conf

```
set $i l;
return 202 "Hel${i}o world!\n";
```

In action:

```
opti# curl -6v "http://localhost/"
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Server: nginx/1.4.1
< Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 18:02:08 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 13
< Connection: keep-alive
<
Hello world!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code has three `e`'s and three `l`'s!

Comment: One of the duplicate `l`'s can be removed easily. `e` is harder, unless nginx is case-insensitive

Comment: Don't forget the spaces!

Comment: And 3×'r', as well

Answer (score 3):

## HTML — 17 characters

```
He&#x6c;lo world!
```

In action:

```
%echo -n "He&#x6c;lo world!" | wc
       0       2      17
%echo -n "He&#x6c;lo world!" | lynx -dump -stdin

   Hello world!

%
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Fugue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fugue)

From the esolang wiki:

[image]

And you can [listen to the source code](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/files/fugue/src/hworld.mid).

Comment: I'd say this is invalid. I can see more than 4 middle c's in the right hand.

Comment: Not to mention the string of four consecutive G's in the 9th measure.

Comment: Did you write this, or only render it? Given that you link to the esolang archive's MIDI.

Comment: -1 for plagiarism. This is from [esolang wiki](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hello_world_program_in_esoteric_languages#Fugue). You do not cite it. Edit: reverted, now the esolang wiki is cited.

Comment: -1 for using the same note more than 2 times.

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure (35)

`(printf "He%c%co world!\n",108,108)`

The whitespace almost got me, but Clojure allows the use of commas to separate parameters.

Comment: You could always have used different types of whitespace--space, newline, tab, vertical tab, form feed.  I'm not completely sure of Clojure's grammar off the top of my head, but the first tree ones would likely work at least.

Comment: But it was interesting to try out this use of commas in Clojure. I *thought* I'd read somewhere that they could be used to substitute for whitespace but hadn't messed with it.

Comment: As MrWonderful pointed out for my Scala version, you're only using a single 'l'. You could save a few characters by using your second, for `(printf "Hel%co world!\n",108)`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 28 chars

```
printf"He%so world!\n",'l'x2
```

Rules tested with:

```
perl -e '$"="\n";@a=split//,<>;print"@a";' | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (32 characters)

```
main(){puts("He\x6clo world!");}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Plain TeX - 18 chars

```
He^^,lo world!\bye
```

Remark: TeX terminates the paragraph before shipping it, so the "newline" is actually included.

Answer (score 3):

## Taking it directly from the instructions on this page:

```
curl -sL bit.do/gBfx|perl -E'@Q=map{m%OUtPUTS The chARAC.ERS\N*?>([^<]+)%i?$1:()}<>;say$Q[1]'
```

or, if you wanna be strict with the white-spaces:

## PERL

```
`curl -sL v.gd/92XIMS`=~m%ThE\WChAracTERS.*?>\K[^<]+%i;say$&
```

or

```
`curl -sL v.gd/qmwAMh`=~m%outpUtS\WTHE\WChAracTERS.*?>([^<]+)%i;say$1
```

**Advantage:** will work for every sentence, but *please don't* change wording of the question :)

**Rules:** we can consider this question being an "internal" resource. Without *this question*, no one would solve it. **Should it be me or the program reading it? :)**

**Backstage story:** I almost teared out all my hair trying to debug this! :)

First solution

- using `wget -O-` leads to 3x `-`
- `sed` needed too many `/`
- so I need cur`l` and per`l`, but all perl loops like `until`, `while` contain 3rd `l`!
- I needed to replace the loop, this is quite complicated but

  - it seems `$1` only works after positive (`=~`) not negative (`!~`) match
  - I couldn't use `!(..)` - too many parentheses :x
  - neither I could use `||` (I need a pipe!) or `or` (pe`r`l, cu`r`l ...)

Second solution

- I reread the rules. White-spaces shouldn't be repeated either - oh my!
- At least could recycle the `do{}while` idea. Better said, it was forced, the map solution could not be used for using `()` 2 times, 3rd needed to call `open` since no more whitespaces are left.
- Find proper url shortener was a story, using `goo.gl`, `bit.ly`, `is.gd` or `ow.ly` was obviously impossible for the first solution, as was `bit.do` and `dft.ba` for the second. Then, url-shorten the URL until you get something you can use, especially with `bit.ly` and `v.gd`. Why on earth they use so much lowercase characters?

The regex could be shortened, but I like the instructions to be as long as possible :-)

These rules are damn crazy :)

---

<sub>PERL v5.10 say feature has to be enabled, e.g. by running PERL `-E` option</sub>

Comment: For the first one, you have a backslash left, right? You could do two tabs and one escaped newline for the spaces in the shell part.

Comment: @FireFly what a neat idea :) I don't now why I limited myself to spaces. I guess because I like one-liners that can just be copy-pasted :)

Answer (score 3):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 13 bytes

The winner was chosen, but I still want to do it. :) (Astonishingly it is shorter than HTML!)

```
Hel:o world\!
```

This is a popularity contest, but the program is very easy to understand despite of the conciseness.

### Explanation

```
Hel          #Push "Hel" onto the stack
   :         #Duplicate the top of the stack (l)
    o world  #Push "o world" onto the stack
           \!#Escape ! and push it onto the stack(since it is an instruction)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), C# Expression - 22 chars

```
"Hello w\x6fr\x006cd!"
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 30 characters

Highly inspired by [Vereos's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18749/14811).

```
<?=Hello.' wor'.chr(108),"d!";
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML - (16 Chars):**

```
Hello Wor&#108d!
```

Proper HTML would be to put a `;` after `&#108` but it still compiles fine. :)

Comment: HTML... compiles fine?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, it compiles fine. It is a good practice to put a `;` at the end of it, but it still compiles.

Comment: Oh wait, now I get it. You're creating .chm files! Sorry I didn't get that the first time.

Comment: @MrLister, Uh... No. I'm making .htm files.

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree; that would be easier.

Comment: @MrLister I don't follow...

Comment: That's alright, I don't follow either.

Answer (score 2):

### C

```
q=7103816;
main(){printf("%slo world!%c",&q,2+8);}
```

Works on little-endian platforms, where `7103816` is encoded the same as `Hel\0`.

Comment: Missing \n at the end.

Comment: Thanks @mcleod_ideafix. I was going to simply add `\n`, but I'm out of `n`s. Fortunately, I had `%` and `,` to spare.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua - 22 characters

```
print"Hel\108o World!"
```

Simple enough, example output

```
lua -e 'print"Hel\108o World!"'
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 19ch

> `'Hello Wor\154d!\n'`

Character count:

> `"'Hello Wor\154d!\n'".length` -> 15 //cough, cheating

> `"'Hello Wor\\154d!\\n'".length` -> 19

With your choice of `return`, `alert()`, or nothing? Man, javascript has too many contexts.

Slightly more interesting: `["He",,'o World\n'].join('l')`

Comment: Your correct variant has 4 times ``\`` I think ;)

Answer (score 2):

## **Яussian**

`Хелло мир!`

A mix of transliteration and proper language :) Google translate will turn it into proper "Hello world!"

Comment: I guess this wouldn't even be accepted in a code-trolling question, lol. Nice interpretation of the `In a language of your choice` sentence, but here's Programming Puzzles and Code Golf site!

Answer (score 2):

## C, 41

```
main(){printf("He%clo world!%c",108,10);}
```

Comment: You're using the character `n` three times.  (`main`, `printf`, `\n`)

Comment: Good work replacing the `\n` but your score was wrong. I updated the `33` to `41`.

Answer (score 2):

### R

Not gonna win anything, but I didn't see R yet...

```
'He\154\154o, World!'
'Hello, Wor\154d!'
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 33 bytes on-calculator

```
"l→Str1:Disp "He..o World!
Str1:Output(2,3,Ans+Ans
```

Since TI-BASIC uses tokens instead of characters, I limited myself by token. Make sure the screen is cleared before running the program. Note that l and o are two-byte tokens, but w is a sequence variable and d, e, and r are statistics variables, which are all one-byte tokens. This program first **Disp**lays the string without the first two l's, and then uses a different command to paste in the other two. Also note that TI-BASIC has no equivalent to a newline, but when the program ends the cursor does move down to allow further input to the calculator.

Comment: Oh wait, I used 4 commas. I will have to redo this

Comment: Wait, this doesn't work at all because Disp overwrites Ans.

Comment: Fixed. I now made use of both Str1 and Ans.

Answer (score 1):

### [Hexish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexish)

```
0B
```

Comment: According to the documentation that prints `hello world`.  We need a capital `H`, a `!`, and a newline.  Close, but no cigar!

Comment: @Josh Closer than you think... it actually prints `Hello World!`

Comment: Ehm, the Esolang page says that this language falls under the category "Unimplemented". Is that allowed? I mean, are unimplemented languages allowed?

Comment: In that case, I will now invent a new language SECODEGOLF where every program consists of a single decimal number, and the output is the solution to the corresponding CodeGolf question. For instance, the program `18721` would print "Hello World!" and a newline.

Comment: @MrLister Arguably SECODEGOLF is *mostly* implemented by this website. (Part of the implementation is crowd-sourced.) And most languages' specifications are only *mostly* implemented. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 27

`main=print"Hello Wor\108d!"`

Twice-check:

```
import Data.List
main=getContents>>=print.all((<3).length).group.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28programming_language_from_Kx_Systems%29) [16 chars]

```
"hel\154o world"
```

Comment: itym `-1"Hel\154o world!";`

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js - 54 Unicode characters

```
eval([]+Buffer('consolť.ŬůgĨĢHťŬɬů wɯrɬd!Ģĩ',"ascii"))
```

console.log outputs a given string and a line shift, unfortunately that initially leaves me with way too many `l`s and `o`s, so it took some work.

The code creates a buffer from a string and is told to use ascii encoding, this effectively takes all character values mod 256 and stores them in the buffer, the buffer is then added to an empty array, which cause both buffer and array to be converted to string before the addition, an empty array converts to an empty string, and the buffer is implicitly converted using UTF-8 encoding. The result is evaled to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.1.2+

```
<?="\x48".hasH_file(@cRC32b,__FILE__,'« Tý'|5)." wor\X6Cd!";
```

The code hashes itself to get the remaining characters. Repeats the characters ".\,'_

A tab messes up the formatting. Base64:

> PD89Ilx4NDgiLmhhc0hfZmlsZShAY1JDMzJiLF9fRklMRV9fLCfCqwlUw70nfDUpLiIgd29yXFg2Q2QhIjs=

Comment: Nice hack, but I count 4 underscores.

Comment: @eBusiness Five `_` actually, and four times `"` :)

Answer (score 1):

### newLISP

Such a cruel challenge for a Lisp-like language, where so much is possible if only you don't count parentheses... :) But a solution can be found:

```
 (eval-string(encrypt {`4?3%;=6^9z*9&^m=>*],c;W}{HDMZKOQX~B2OUJ1MJQX1HBF~KU2FZD}))
```

(81 characters)

which uses the simple `encrypt` function to pass a command through to the evaluator. The actual command is `(println {Hello world!})`. (Having "z" and "Z" and "Z" is allowed, according to the comments...:)).

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX shell (Bash et al) - 26 chars

```
printf 'Hel\x6Co world!\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

## k/q (25 chars)

`-1@.h.uh"Hello wor%6cd!";`

works in either k or q

(btw, the validity can be checked elegantly with `|/#:'="-1@.h.uh\"Hello wor%6cd!\";"`)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**
I am amazed at how many people give invalid answers without mentioning they are.
My attempt, only reusing `o"` characters twice.

`<?Php EchO "Hello wor\154d!";`

*Edit: fixed thanks to @FireFly: i understood to use each character once. This is no challenge anymore.*

Comment: Wouldn't changing the `\X6C` into `l` make it completely valid? I only see one other `l` in there.

Answer (score 1):

## Active Server Pages (Classic ASP):

```
Hel<%REspOnsE.wRite Chr((0<0>-.6&"!")+&H6C+h-dinptO)
%>o world!
```

---

**Each character is used twice!**

To run it, you'll need a web server running IIS.

Save it in the site root with a ".asp" extension, make a HTTP request to the server, and you'll see that the response text is exactly "Hello world!" and a new line:

```
Hello world!
```

---

**Edit:** You could also use this smaller code:

```
Hel<%= Chr((0<0>we=6&"!")+&H6C+hd)
%>o world!
```

Or this:

```
Hel<%= CHr((0<1>wedC=8&"!&")++108)
%>o world!
```

Answer (score 1):

http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hello%2B%2B

```
H
```

1 letter is all it takes to print that

Answer (score 1):

BASH

printf "a\107Vs\x62G8gd29ybGQhCg=="|base64 -d

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (52 characters)

```
alert(['He\x6C\x6Co world!'][(!1,0)-0], +-1+"Hadtw")
```

Each character is used 2 times, and it doesn't use any comments!

**Edit**: *I've just posted the same answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19590/15022).*

Answer (score 0):

## c-41

```
main(){printf("He%clo world!%c",154,10);}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in general: http://codepad.org/O09aQhCe - on what platform does character code 186 give you 'll' ?

Comment: In MS-DOS (code page 437 and similar) character with code 186 is double vertical line, used for drawing frames.

Comment: It's 38 chars. You missed '!'. Besides, the two vertical bars are not two L's

Comment: It produces this output: He||o world! I'm using code blocks

Comment: Without ending '\n' this answer contains 35 chars. And output looks wery similar to `Hello world!`. But this answer may be wroted shorter as `main(){puts("He║o world!");}`

Comment: @AMK thanks I guess adding the vertical bars was a bad idea from the first.

Comment: Question states: "**exactly** outputs the characters **Hello world!**"

Comment: @Darren that's why I edited it.

Comment: I don't think you're compiling and running your submission, @user689.  When I compile and run your program, I get the output `He%clo world!%c`. This is expected, since `puts` does not allow `printf` style formatting.

Comment: Oops you are right @Darren

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 35

With inspiration from @VisioN

```
alert(atob("SGVsbG8gV29y")+'ld!\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 21 bytes

```
puts Hello\ wor\x6cd!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWMEjNScnP0ahPL8opsIsOUXx/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC

```
?@H[1]+@e[!0];CHR$(108);"lo world!
```

Another solution:

```
CLS?"He__o world!
LOCATE 2,0?@l[1]*2
```

Answer (score -1):

In C. Choose one of these.

My favourite (crazy but compact in memory):

```
#include <stdint.h>
printf("%s", (char*)(int32_t[]){1819043144,1870078063,6581362});
```

For those who like big numbers:

```
printf("%s", (char*)(int64_t[]){8031924123371070792,43509902450});
```

Or here the more descriptive versions:

```
printf("%s", (char*)(int32_t[]){0x6c6c6548,0x6f77206f,0x646c72});
printf("%s", (char*)(int64_t[]){0x6f77206f6c6c6548,0x0a21646c72});
```

char map:

```
H  e  l  l     o     w  o     r  l  d  !     <LF>
48 65 6c 6c    6f 20 77 6f    72 6c 64 21    0a
(remember to swap big/little endian bytes when composing)
```

Btw: why there is no 128 bit integer in C?

```
printf("%s", (char*)(int128_t[]){0x0a21646c726f77206f6c6c6548});
printf("%s", (char*)(int128_t[]){802616035175250124568770929992}); // string uses only 100 of 128 bits
```

Comment: These don't met the requirements as some characters are used more than twice. Eg ( ) 0 1 2 9 etc etc

Comment: When I look at the example in the question, I see `print("He%so world!"%(2*'l'))` which is 1p 2r 1i 1n 1t 2( 2" 1H 1e 2% etc. Even when I focus to the string I still see 2 o's, so why should my answer follow the rules when the question doesn't? ;-)

Comment: printf("%s", (char*)(int32_t[]){1819043144,1870078063,6581362});

( x 3,  ) x 3, 1 x 5, 3 x 3, 4 x 4, 6 x 3, 8 x 4

Comment: Ok, I see. I misunderstood the specs. But I'm not the only one, when I look at the bash + ruby solutions of SztupY and the solution of cnst

Comment: Just because someone else didn't follow the rules doesn't justify you.

Answer (score -1):

AWK and echo

EDIT:   fix the extra o's following the note. (thanks ProgramFOX)

```
echo He: | awk -F: '{print $1,Q,"\157 Wor",Q}' OFS=l ORS=d\!
```

and thanks awk which give me the option to say "-F" instead of "IFS="
(:-)

Comment: There are too many spaces, too. after `echo`, after `He:`, after `|`, and so on.

Answer (score -2):

**Java**

Okay I found this on SO, it doesn't output a big `H`

Rare sequence of random stream of digits for 2 specific seeds.
Probably fixed out by brute forcing
One of the SO solutions also include a brute forcer to make your own sequences.

```
System.out.println(randomString(-229985452) + " " + randomString(-147909649) + "!");
```

And `randomString()` looks like this

```
public static String randomString(int i)
{
    Random ran = new Random(i);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int n = 0; ; n++)
    {
        int k = ran.nextInt(27);
        if (k == 0)
            break;

        sb.append((char)('`' + k));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182496/why-does-this-code-print-hello-world

Comment: And this meets the specs, how? I can easily count 3 `S`'s, 3 spaces, 3 `2`'s, etc.