# The Quickest Fox in the East

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source

In the spirit of [Hello world! with NO repetition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/hello-world-with-no-repetition)

Write a program that prints the string "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" with optional newline. The entire program must not repeat any characters.

Note that the string to be printed *does* repeat characters, so you will have to get around that limitation somehow.

Note that the winning condition is [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), i.e. *the highest-voted answer* wins.

Update: To make this a little easier, repetition is allowed but you must attempt to minimize it. Programs with less (or no) repetition are given precedence over programs with some repetition.

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably too hard, if not outright impossible.  `Hello world!` without repetitions was hard enough that people had to resort to very niche languages or outright couldn't solve the task completely at all, and this one is considerably harder on top of that.

Comment: Well, it sure is impossible in C. You can't call functions or use macros.

Comment: I recommend: print the given string _with as few repeated characters as possible_.

Comment: @FireFly didn't take long to have answers :)

Comment: @SirDarius apparently so. I'm impressed.

Comment: @FireFly Added a clause allowing people to use repetition anyway, we may get some interesting answers.

Comment: I was seriously considering trying to do this in C#, but immediately realised that any valid program needs to sets of curly brackets :(

Answer (score 33):

## Microsoft Word from 97 to 2003 (and some Mac Word versions) — 10 characters

No repetitions, but doesn't quite match specs - 10 characters:

```
=rand(2,1)
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Matches specs, other than capitalization and punctuation, one repetition - 10 characters:

```
=rand(1,1)
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Newer versions of Microsoft Word use `=rand.old(1,1)` which duplicates `d` and `1`.

There might be a way to use a field `{=SUM(3,-2)}` as input to rand() but my installation is having issues with fields -- namely, they're not working...

"Bob" has confirmed that `{=SUM(3,-2)}` (with some difficulty) can be used to replace the first `1`, but `=` is repeated...

```
=rand({=SUM(3,-2)},1)
```

Provided you get Word to update `SUM` first, the output is:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: I'm not sure the given syntax is right, but I don't have any systems that old to test it on. For newer versions though, it should be `=rand.old(1,1)`. I suppose you're trying to use 3-2 to replace the first 1, but it doesn't appear to be working for me in 2010 with rand.old or rand.

Comment: I don't have a system here either, will check when I get home. Might need to use braces `{ ... }` as delimiters, but I'm pretty sure expressions can be used in any function. If not, I'll revise!

Comment: I can confirm the `{=SUM(3,-2)}` works in Word 2007. But the method is a bit complicated. First, you must insert a field code (Ctrl + F9). Then, right click => edit field => formula => advanced => type in the formula. Because typing it in directly doesn't work for whatever reason. Now click in the field and evaluate with Shift + F9. And add the `=rand.old()`

Comment: Is it necessary to use `=SUM`, or could simply use arithmetic operators directly, as `3-2`?

Comment: @supercat - We tried that, and for some reason, Word does not accept expressions as parameters of `=rand()`, e.g. `=rand(3-2,1)` would be perfect. I actually didn't try `=rand({=3-2},1)`, but it should work the same way, with duplication of `=`.

Answer (score 17):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting) — 36 characters

```
덆둥긇굵늖꽫긆깲닷덮긂롦닲롸껂걪덖륰댲걯덦넬댢건늆넠닆굺뎒걤닶댬首坼
```

(expects empty input)

### Explanation:

```
Push the string "the quick brown ,fo,x, jumps ove,r the lazy dog,"
덆둥긇굵늖꽫긆깲닷덮긂롦닲롸껂걪덖륰댲걯덦넬댢건늆넠닆굺뎒걤닶댬
Retrieve last character from the string (",")
首
Regular expression string-split
坼
```

The result is the list `["the quick brown ", "fo", "x", " jumps ove", "r the lazy dog", ""]`, which is automatically concatenated into a single string for output.

Comment: I count 105 bytes, not to mention several repeats. Char _235_, for example, is used 20 times.

Comment: "Must not repeat any *characters*", not "must not repeat any bytes".

Comment: I'm not surprised Timwi, your own language is perfect for "no repeated characters" challenges.

Answer (score 13):

### Perl 6 (76 chars, no doubles)

The script (will be mangled by the board software, but there's En Space up to Thin Space and NL and LF and tab)

```
say　EVAL    lc q{<the Quiţk Brown fïX jUmpS ůvťɲ Tɨå ìšzY dOg>~&(127.CHR
x
43)}
```

- It uses EVAL (thanks again for making it uppercase) and `<foo bar>` quote words which supports all the special space characters as word separators.
- `say` joins the list of strings using space, works nicely here :)
- Next I use `~&` and 127 to bit shuffle to plain ascii. Extra complication: `'Ŭ'.lc` becomes `'ŭ'` so that becomes an `s` instead of the `r` I needed. Adding 128 some extra times helps :)

A version with backslash escapes instead of unicode characters to show they're all different

```
say\x[3000]EVAL\x[9]lc q{<the\x[2003]Qui\x[163]k\x[2004]Brown\x[2005]f\x[EF]X\x[2006]jUmpS\x[2007]\x[16F]v\x[165]\x[272]\x[2008]T\x[268]\x[E5]\x[2009]\x[EC]\x[161]zY\x[200A]dOg>~&(127.CHR\x[0A]x\x[0D]43)}
```

If you want to verify they're all unique, use this script (I used `Qb"string"` to have basic quoting with only backslash escapes)

```
.say for 
Qb"say\x[3000]EVAL\x[9]lc q{<the\x[2003]Qui\x[163]k\x[2004]Brown\x[2005]f\x[EF]X\x[2006]jUmpS\x[2007]\x[16F]v\x[165]\x[272]\x[2008]T\x[268]\x[E5]\x[2009]\x[EC]\x[161]zY\x[200A]dOg>~&(127.CHR\x[0A]x\x[0D]43)}"
.comb.Bag.grep(*.value > 1).map: {.key.ord.base(16) ~ " $_"  }
```

Or execute it directly using

```
EVAL Qb"say\x[3000]EVAL\x[9]lc q{<the\x[2003]Qui\x[163]k\x[2004]Brown\x[2005]f\x[EF]X\x[2006]jUmpS\x[2007]\x[16F]v\x[165]\x[272]\x[2008]T\x[268]\x[E5]\x[2009]\x[EC]\x[161]zY\x[200A]dOg>~&(127.CHR\x[0A]x\x[0D]43)}"
```

Answer (score 10):

### PHP - 67 bytes

```
<?echo$g^¶¥€¼½ˆ•.${~˜}=ÂÍåœÌýü¡¦Åþ¾’‹Ï†£‘Æ²áºëÓâæÝ—ß™ó–Ž¸·³ø‰ï®ÜØÔ;
```

*Copy-Paste, save as Latin-1 (Ansi).*

This is a 7-byte xor-cipher, using the string `¶¥€¼½ˆ•` for salt.

One repeated character: `$`.

Comment: You can shorten it another 3 character by using `<?=` since you are already using short tags

Comment: Ah, sorry, just noticed you already use =

Comment: @KristofferSHansen I think it should be possible to use `eval('Return$g=binary;')` in some cryptic form (perhaps bit inversion) to avoid the `$` repetition, and then the `=` would be freed up as well.

Comment: The opening tag should not be included in the byte count.

Comment: @TecBrat The final `;` can be replaced by closing tag: should that not be counted either? In short, I disagree. If your code doesn't run as-is, it's not a complete program.

Comment: This `php -r 'echo "Hello World\n";'` at the command line writes `Hello World` and a line break. Wouldn't it be correct to only count `echo "Hello World\n";` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 71 characters

```
map(\c->chr$mod(ord c)128)"tŨeఠquiţkĠbŲɯwnȠfѯxРjѵŭŰsܠůvťѲठѴѨѥਠlšzyଠɤկg"
```

Yet another 7-bit modulo solution.

Repeated characters:

```
c 3
d 2
m 2
o 2
r 2
( 2
) 2
" 2
```

First time golfing with Haskell; anyone more experienced in the language, feel free to improve. I wanted to make the anonymous function point-free to avoid having to mention a variable twice, but I don't know if it'd be a net benefit.