# "Hello world!", repeating each character n times

Tags: popularity-contest, hello-world, restricted-source

In your language of choice, write a program that outputs exactly `Hello world!`. Each character in your program must be repeated *n* times - you choose *n*.

For example, you might choose 2 for *n*. This means that every character used in your source code *must* be repeated that many times, or 0.

If I were to choose 3 for *n*, this program would be valid:

```
ab(b(b(aa)));;;
```

Rules:

- You cannot use any external resources
- No user input can be provided
- You must output *exactly* `Hello world!`, no more, no less. Newlines are the exception, they are optional.
- *n* must be >= 2, to keep things interesting
- It's highly discouraged to use comments to accomplish your goal.

Popularity contest, ending in 14 days. Highest score answer at the end wins!

Comment: Let's steal every answers from this topic: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/hello-world-with-no-repetition with n=1

Comment: Oops, let's say that `n>=2`, @Fabinout

Comment: Space counts as a character?

Comment: @3ventic Yes, it does.

Comment: [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ALdu/) I threw together for testing if anyone needs it

Comment: I'd love to see a HQ9+ solution for this.

Comment: @Nate HQ9+ outputs a comma (as noted in a deleted answer). ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Brainfuck

n=57. 45 newlines removed thanks to ratchet freak

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<++++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.>+.---------------------------------[.............................................][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]<-<<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><
```

A more readable version:

```
+++++ +++++ [
    > +++++ ++
    > +++++ +++++
    > +++
    <<< -
]
> ++ .
> + .
+++++ ++.
.
+++ .
> ++ .
< +++++ +++ .
----- --- .
+++ .
----- - .
----- --- .
> + .
---------------------------------[.............................................][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]<-<<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><
```

The last line (on the readable version) is for filling up the character count. They are not comments. The `[]` are `while(0)`s, and the `><`s are in essence no-ops

Comment: couldn't you put the `.` inside one of the `[]` and not output the newlines

Comment: @ratchet freak Good point. Thanks.

Comment: I think ratchet was suggesting moving the `[` in the first `[]` to before the dots, so that it wouldn't output even NULLs.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen Oh right, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript

```
alert(("aaaeerrttt((,,,HHHoo   wwwddd!!!))","Hello world!"))
```

This seemed a little too easy.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, n = 3, no comments

```
dwwppHottedHen =print((("H[e]l1l1o\\ !w!orrilidn!\""[::2][:12])))== 2
```

Not too hard for a Pythonist to understand. ;) (Hint: try `"abcdefghijk"[::2]` and see what it results in)

By the way, a `HottedHen` is a warmed up chicken, if you were wondering. (The `dwwpp` before it stands for `drinking water with purple pancakes`, because that's what the hens were doing when I was writing it. Everyone knows that purple pancakes go well with water. Obviously.)

Answer (score 10):

### C, 54

```c
main(Hadmeinwurst015p){{!puts("Hello\40wor\154d!");;}}
```

Comment: You have  a v that doesn't match

Comment: @Eduard hm, you're right, it must've slipped in there accidentally because it doesn't seem to have been included in the character count... fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### Golfscript - 32

New version with 2 of each used character - 32 - [Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJIZWxsbyB3b3JceDZjZCEiICdcSGV3cng2Y2QhJzs=)

```
;"Hello wor\x6cd!" '\Hewrx6cd!';
```

Old version - 39 - [Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzsnSGVsbG8gd29ybGQhJyAgIidISGVld3dvcnJkZCEhXFxcIiI7)

```
;;'Hello world!'  "'HHeewworrdd!!\\\"";
```

EDIT: Updated since rules was updated saying it was discouraged with the use of comments

Comment: Much better without comments!

Answer (score 4):

## Java - 1221 chars

Each character is repeated `(int)'!'` number of times.

```
public class ncharacterHelloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        {;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;
{;{;{;{;{;{;{;{;{;{;{;{
String pppppppppppppppuuuuuuuuuuuuuubbbbbbbbbbbbbbbllllllllllliiiiiiiiiiicccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssnnnnnnnnnnnnnhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttteeeeeeeeeeeeeeHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwdddddddddddddddvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSgggggggggggggggyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy="Hello world!",
a=pppppppppppppppuuuuuuuuuuuuuubbbbbbbbbbbbbbbllllllllllliiiiiiiiiiicccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssnnnnnnnnnnnnnhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttteeeeeeeeeeeeeeHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwdddddddddddddddvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSgggggggggggggggyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy,
u="\"=============================,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...............................",b="\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\\\\\\a",i,l,c,t,H,o,w,m;int[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
        if(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!(!!true)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
System.out.println(a);
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
    }




}
```

I got tired of putting all the `=` and `,` and the like in the code, so I ended dumping them all in a String; not a comment, a string. Every valid character is used for a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

### Windows Command Script - 33 bytes

3 of everything:

```
ecHo Hello world!% eHccwwrrdd!!%%
```

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Command Line - 42 Bytes

n=3

```
ecHo.Hello world! 2>^>2cceHwwrrdd!.. 2>^^!
```

### Batch - 45 Bytes

```
@ecHo.Hello world! 2>^>2cceHwwrrdd@@..! 2>^^!
```

`2>` redirects stderr to a file called `>22cceHwwrrdd` - `>` is an invalid character for a file name - redirect the output of that error to a file called `^!`.

Realized that I completely ignored `!` and `>`. Dang.

Comment: I spy 4 spaces :(

Answer (score 3):

## **Ruby - 40 Chars** (n=2)

```
print "Hel\x6co World!"||'pintHe\x6cWd!'
```

Comment: How many spaces do you have? Is it correct to say that the first two around `p` are tabs (or something similar)?

Comment: @Quincunx First space was a typo.Now edited

Answer (score 3):

### PHP - 30 bytes, *n = 2*

```
Hell<?='=s?<;^2s'^RSHSI2VReIV;
```

Shortest solution thus far. I may be able to reduce this by *2-4* more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP

```php
<?print"H\145llo wor\154d!"; $Hwpintd<>!'$';?>
```

Shorter version (42 char):

```php
<?print"H\145llo wor\154d!"; 'Hwd<pint?!';
```

[Online page with that source](http://dev.twisted-gamers.net/test.php)

Comment: I think you can:
- not end with ?> (which will eliminate the use of >)
- treat Hepwintd<! as string - `'Hepwintd<!'` which will take care of $

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (51 bytes)

```
print'Hello world!'; ppriinnttHHeeowwdd; "'\"\\!!";
```

Comment: Old post and probably doesn't matter too much, but you can save a few bytes using `$'` or `$"` inside a `q!!` block instead of the `\\`s.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>75</s> <s>56</s> 54

2 of everything

```
main(HWacdeimnprstux6) {{!puts("Hel\x6co\ World!");;}}
```

---

```
main( ){puts("Hello Wor\x6cd!\0!;HWacdeimnprstux06{}");}
```

---

3 of everything.

```
main(){puts("Hello World!\000!!;;HHWWaaddeeiimmnnpprrssttuu{}{}\"\()o");}
```

`Puts` stops reading after the first null byte (`\000`), and only outputs everything before it.

Comment: In the first `i` is kind of lonely! :)

Comment: Your first two have only one `i` (easy to fix: change the `main` argument name). Your last only has one space

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Lol, I posted that *exactly* at the same time as you :P

Comment: Oops, the first was missing. The second had it, just out of place.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 40 (n=2)

I took a slightly different approach to @eithedog, using the left over letters to act as a logic trigger, so that it was absolutely essential to use it to activate the `alert` function.

`('Hawtd !')&&alert("He\x6c\x6co world!")`

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2, 38**

```
deinptw=H=5; print"Hel\154o world\41";
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 346 characters, *n* = 12

```
cat((((((((((intToUtf8(c(40,69,76,76,79,0,55,79,82,76,68,1)+31+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0++0*11111111[1]*22222222222[1]*33333333333[1]*44444444444[1]*5555555555[1]*6666666[1]*7777777[1]*888888888[1]*999999*9[1]*9[1]*9[1])))))))))),"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\\aaaaaaaaaaaccccccccccfffffffffffiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooootttttttttTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUU"[0])
```

Characters used in this code:

```
,"()[]*\+0123456789acfinotTU
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) (non-competing)

```
“⁸ƒẹI4»
“⁸ƒẹI4»
```

(+trailing newline)

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net#code=4oCc4oG4xpLhurlJNMK7CuKAnOKBuMaS4bq5STTCuwo) (n = 2)

NO COMMENTS AT ALL. I assure you. Just Link 1 and the Main Link.

Comment: And yes I know this is not [tag:code-golf].

Comment: Hmm... so this answer paved the road to close for this challenge. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

### Golfscript, 42

```
."Hello world!"'\\\'"  HHeeowwrrdd!!'..;;;
```

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=LiJIZWxsbyB3b3JsZCEiJ1xcXCciICBISGVlb3d3cnJkZCEhJy4uOzs7)

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript, 40**

```
alert("Hel\x6Co wor\x6Cd!", !('adtHw,'))
```

If I'm not mistaken every character appears twice (though I started seeing double, so I'm not sure)

edit: And, if abusing the rules - **36**:

```
alert("Hel\x6Co wor\x6Cd!")( !wdatH)
```

(abuse = while output is given as a prompt, the console displays the error - don't know how to treat this).

Comment: `r` appears 3 times while `w` only appears once. (in both versions) Just replace the final `r` with `w` to fix it

Comment: Oh, dyslexia, you cruel mistress... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Python:

With 3 characters each.

```
print 'Hello world!'#He's aware#paints#Hipos!nddwt!
```

`nddwt` is a rhino!

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 39

```
echo -e "H\r--w\"!wccdd!\rHello world!"
```

This *displays* exactly Hello world!, and is 39 chars if you omit the trailing newline (bash doesn't seem to need it).

If you need a case-sensitive version, it becomes 42 chars:

```
echo -e "HhhH\r--w\"!wccdd!\rHello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (52 characters)

```
alert(['He\x6C\x6Co world!'][(!1,0)-0], +-1+"Hadtw")
```

Each character is used 2 times, and it doesn't use any comments!

**Note:** *I posted this answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19589/15022) first.*

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript x4 -- No extra symbols -- Using all possible commands

```
'HHHeeelWWWrrrd'!!! do do 'Hello world!'
```

I tried to do one that didn't have any extra symbols beyond what was absolutely necessary (though I could have chosen `"` instead of `'` or `"`)

As a secondary goal I also wanted to put as few characters as possible into a string
as possible, so I used the `!` operator as such, and I also squeezed in to `do` operators.

Answer (score 0):

## Classic ASP (VBScript; 62 characters)

```
Hel<%REspOnsE.wRite Chr((0<0>-.6&"!")+&H6C+h-dinptO)%>o world!
```

Uses each character exactly 2 times!

---

**Edit:** This code is a bit shorter:

```
Hel<%= Chr((0<0>we=6&"!")+&H6C+hd)%>o world!
```

And so is this:

```
Hel<%= CHr((0<1>wedC=8&"!&")++108)%>o world!
```

Answer (score 0):

## Turtlèd, n=3, (noncompeting)

N=3, because of "Hello world!" having three `l`s.

```
'!' ' HHeeowwrrdd"Hello world!""!
```

**[Try it online](http://turtled.tryitonline.net/#code=JyEnICcgSEhlZW9XV3JyZGQiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIiIh&input=)**

### Explanation:

```
'!                                write exclamation mark
  ' '                             write space twice on the same cell as exclamation mark
      HHeeowwrrdd                 balances chars in Hello world!, moves the pointer
                 "Hello world!"   Write Hello world! to grid
                               "! Write the exclamation mark again, on top of the last one
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge 98 - 26 bytes

Since I had to duplicate the `r` anyway, I figured I may as well make the source text read left-to-right rather than typical `gnirts` Befunge style. There's nothing particularly notable about this; I'm not sure if having code that simply isn't executed counts as a comment, but the six characters `Hel w!` are just ignored.

```
rHel w!@,dk"Hello, world!"
```