# Alphanumeric Hello World

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source, hello-world

Your goal is to write "Hello, World!" (minus the quotes). This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so most up votes  wins. Code length will be used to break ties.
Anything goes, as long as it is within the following rules:

- All characters must be either letters or numbers, so you may only use characters in the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".
- All code you use must be in one file, with the exception of imported modules/classes/whatever they're called in your favourite language.
- Only the standard libraries/frameworks for your language of choice are allowed (for example, Python's Math module is allowed, but Numpy, Scipy, and Pygame are not). I will allow TkInter as it is the de facto standard for GUIs in Python.
- No input is permitted, be it reading from stdin, reading a file, displying an image, or reading from the web.

+10 brownie points if you figure out how to do it in Java without bending the rules.

---

On your marks, get set, code!

EDIT: braces ({}), brackets ([]), and parentheses (()) are allowed as this would be pretty much impossible for most languages without them. I'm also removing the character limit rule. Hopefully this will make it more interesting.

EDIT^2: white space is also allowed. My brain isn't working properly, sorry. >.<

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain his/her vote? I'dlike to know how I could make this better.

Comment: Didn't DV, but what do you mean when you say "all characters must be..." Most languages use other characters for even the most basic tasks: (){}[]/-+., etc. Are those banned?

Comment: Yes, they are. Should I widen the allowed characters a bit to include (), [], and {}?

Comment: Up to you, I'm just making sure. What about whitespace?

Comment: Ok, I think I'll widen the character number restriction, because as it is this is basically a duplicate of [Hello world! With limited character repetition] (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/hello-world-with-limited-character-repetition?rq=1). Does 5 sound like a petter number?

Comment: Oh, right white space. My brain is clearly not functioning properly today. That should be allowed. One second, let me fix the rules.

Comment: What about these: ;?:&<>/\+-,. ?

Comment: So, no operators? And, most importantly, no `;`? How can I write anything in C?

Comment: [esolangs.org Hello, World!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hello_world_program_in_esoteric_languages)

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to exclude J in a natural way: `72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33{a.` requires the period at the end to work, and a path through `u:` similarly requires a colon. Without `.` and `:` we are nothing.

Comment: "I will allow as it is the de facto standard for Python." Allow what?

Comment: Oops, I was talking about TkInter for Python GUIs.

Comment: Damnit. I was thinking of Vim, but you still need to type the !, and the <> need to go around ESC. :/

Comment: No dots or commas? :(

Comment: Java? Impossible. I've been thinking about this for about half an hour and I say there's no way to do it.

Comment: tcl: Possible if `%` is allowed: `puts Hello[format %c 44][format %c 32]World[format %c 33]`

Comment: Can I use a backslash? Then it's possible in Java.

Comment: Python:
`Hello, World!`

An error is raised that has the exact phrase “Hello, World!”.

Comment: This question was [closed on 2016‑05‑15 because it lacked focus](/review/close/30461). The suggested edits by @TheEmptyStringPhotographer [1](/review/suggested-edits/68075) and me [2](/review/suggested-edits/68079) attempting to resolve this issue have been rejected. I think it would be helpful if someone explained how/where the task is “blurry” so we can _focus_ on _one_ thing. To me there is no ambiguity as to what needs to be done to fulfill the task’s goals, but apparently the task is asking for _multiple_ things (i. e. unfocused).

Answer (score 105):

## Perl

Some say perl is a language full of ascii noise and random symbols like `$`... That is not true :P

```
s zzHelloq worldmz and s zqzchr 44ze and s zmzchr 33ze and print
```

> Let's break this up into subexpressions:
>
> ```
> (s zzHelloq worldmz) and (s zqzchr 44ze) and (s zmzchr 33ze) and (print)
> ```
>
> It should be obvious that it executes from left to right as long as every expression returns true. But what on earth is `s zqzchr 44ze`?
>
> In perl, there is a group of ["quote-like operators"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) which includes  `q(str)`, `qw(li st)`, `/regex/`, `s/from/to/` among other things. It turns out all of these operators can use almost any character as a delimeter, with a couple pecularities: opening parethesis has to be closed by a matching closing parenthesis, and if you wish to **use a letter as a delimiter** you have to put a space after the operator letter (to disambiguate it from a bareword).
>
> In this case we see three uses of the `s///` (regex substitution) operator:
>
> ```
> s//Helloq worldm/
> s/q/chr 44/e
> s/m/chr 33/e
> ```
>
> All delimited by the character `z`. The `/e` flag on the last two causes the substitution to be interpreted as code to be evaluated, rather literal text.
>
> A fairly well-known fact about perl is that most operations default to operating on the `$_` builtin variable unless otherwise specified. All these three substitutions and the `print` operate on `$_` in this case, so first we put the words Hello world into the variable, then we fix the punctuation by using the numeric ascii values of the characters, then we print the contents of the variable.

Comment: +1 I don't know what the hell is going on here, but it works!

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That could be the perl motto

Comment: If you could, would you add a small explanation?

Comment: @ace "If you could...." You are implying that he can't. Or that if he did, we wouldn't understand it.

Comment: @steve verrill Sorry, I'm not so good at English. What I mean is that it is possible that he copied it from somewhere without understanding how it works, and if that is the case he wouldn't be able to explain it.

Comment: @ace There's nothing wrong with your English. I was just taking your phrase too literally in order to make a joke.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but in perl a replacement is usually indicated by `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS`, but you can actually use most anything you want instead of the slashes.  The code here uses "z" instead of slashes and turns (nothing) into "Helloq Worldm" then replaces "q" for chr 44 (using the \e flag to evaluate REPLACEMENT aka "chr 44" as an expression) which is ",".  It then replaces "m" with chr 33, a "!", and prints it.

Comment: @ace in a quote-like operator, e.g `q//`, any delimiter can be used, `q!! q** q\\ q;;`. A few exceptions are that to close `(` you use `)`,  `q() q[] q{} q<>`, and that to use an alphanumeric as a delimiter, it should be spaced from the operator to disallow ambiguity, eg `q qq`, `q 66`. The same tricks apply to other quote-like operators.

Comment: +1 just for `s `. I actually muttered "s...space..." aloud to myself and chuckled.

Comment: Aah, Perl ! This is the weirdest answer I have seen on this site.

Comment: I think you should try and write a book using perl...

Comment: I read this as `szarzabar 44 szsmchor33ze aaaand PRINT!`

Answer (score 77):

## C

```c
int main(void) {
  if (putchar(72))
    if (putchar(101))
      if (putchar(putchar(108)))
        if (putchar(111))
          if (putchar(44))
            if (putchar(32))
              if (putchar(87))
                if (putchar(111))
                  if (putchar(114))
                    if (putchar(108))
                      if (putchar(100))
                        if (putchar(33)) 
                        {
                        }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It CAN be done in C. And I thought I'd won this...

Comment: You can do that with switch() as well - beat me to it.

Comment: @Comintern `switch()` uses `:`, as in `case 1:`

Comment: @ace Only if you have cases defined.  You can easily rewrite this as `switch(putchar(72)){}switch(putchar(101)){}`, etc.

Comment: +1 for `putchar(putchar(108))`

Comment: Just missing an "if(putchar(44))" for the comma.

Comment: Well spotted, not sure how I missed the comma in the question. Fixed.

Comment: @mattnewport WOW! I learned a new thing today! Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can't you put `if (putchar(33));` instead of `if (putchar(33)) {}`?

Comment: Not under the stated rules - () and {} are permitted characters but not ;

Answer (score 50):

(edit - BBC basic moved to separate answer as suggested. Most of the votes on this are definitely for the LOGO answer.)

## LOGO

Interpreter at http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/#

```
TO h        pd  fd 100 rt  90  pu  fd 50  rt 90  pd  fd 100  rt 180 fd 50  lt 90  fd 50  rt 90  pu END 
TO e        pu  fd 25  rt  90  pd  fd 25  rt 90  arc 270 25  lt 90  fd 25  lt 90  pu END  
TO l        pd  fd 100 pu  END  
TO o        rt  45 fd  35  pd  arc 360 25  lt  45  pu END 
TO comma    pd  rt 90  arc 90  15  lt  90  pu END 
TO w         l  rt 180 l   pd  lt  135 fd  35  rt  90  fd 35  lt 135  l  END  
TO r        pd  fd 25  rt  90  pu  fd  25  rt 180  arc 180 25 rt 90 END 
TO d         o  rt 135 fd  35  lt  135  l  END      
TO exclaim arc 360 5   fd  10  l  END 
  
clearscreen  
setpencolor 4 pu 
setxy 0 150      h 
setxy 100 150    e  
setxy 200 150    l 
setxy 250 150    l 
setxy 300 150    o 
setxy 350 150    comma  
setpencolor 1 
setxy 0 0        w 
setxy 100 0      o 
setxy 200 0      r  
setxy 300 0      l 
setxy 350 0      d 
setxy 450 0      exclaim 
fd 100
```

Output (the green triangle is the turtle cursor)

[image]

Comment: You should split this answer into two.

Comment: @WallyWest I hardly know the language, but it was the tool for the job. You can print text too (it's called a label on your drawing) but you need a quotation mark for that (I think only the opening quote is required and the closing quote is optional.)

Comment: +1 for drawing it instead of printing words.

Comment: @steveverril The second quote would be a syntax error, actually.

Answer (score 31):

## Applescript

No brackets `[]`, braces `{}` or parentheses `()` at all in this one:

```
set s to ASCII character 72
set s to s as list
set end of s to ASCII character 101
set end of s to ASCII character 108
set end of s to end of s
set end of s to ASCII character 111
set end of s to ASCII character 44
set end of s to space
set end of s to ASCII character 87
set end of s to item 5 of s
set end of s to ASCII character 114
set end of s to third item of s
set end of s to ASCII character 100
set end of s to ASCII character 33
display dialog s as text
```

Output is:
[image]

Comment: Unbelievable! (Having to write the word "character" in full, I mean!) Now I understand what they mean about Apples being expensive. Only joking, +1 for something different :-)

Comment: AppleScript is ridiculously verbose, but the result is it really is one of the most comprehensible programming languages for a layperson.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Hard to write, easy to read

Comment: even C is easier to read...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma IDK. I have no idea what `set s to s as list` does.

Comment: @Cruncher Line 1 assigns the simple ascii char "H" to the scalar variable `s`.  Then line 2 coerces that value to a list.  Thus after line 2, `s` contains a list of one element whose value is "H".  We can then append to that list in the subsequent lines.

Comment: @Cruncher — This is easy. The command `set s to s as list` transforms `"H"` into `{"H"}` (a list). In other languages, like Java, it is usually way more complicated to do that.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Well strictly written it's impossible in Java. You can't change the type of a variable at runtime. However, I would prefer `List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(); s.add(oldS);` ANY DAY. I know exactly what that does when I read it. It makes a list, and puts something in it.

Comment: @Cruncher — I was thinking, more generally, about `set sl to s as list`. In other languages, like Java, it is usually way more complicated to do that.

Comment: @Cruncher — But it is unnatural for humans. We humans first think about the subject and then, *maybe*, about the form.

Answer (score 26):

## Bash

This sort of works, if you squint your eyes:

```
echo NN i NN i i i iNN NNi i i i i i i NN i NN i i i i i i i NNi i i NN NN
echo NN i NNi i i i NN NN i i i i i i iNN i NN i i i i i i i NN i i iNN NN
echo NN i NN iNNNNi NN NN iNNNNi i i i NN i NN iNNNNi NN NN iNN iNNN NN NN
echo NNNNNNN NN iNN NN NN NN iNN i i i NN i NN NN iNN NNN iN NN NN iNNN N
echo NN i NN NNNNNN NN NN NNi NN i i i NN N NN NNi NN NN i i NN NNi iNN N
echo NN i NN NN i i NN NN NN iNN i i i NNN NNN NN iNN NN i i NN NN i NN
echo NN i NN iNNNi iNN NN iNNNNi N i i NN i NN iNNNNi NN i i NN iNNNN N NN
echo i i i i i i i i i i i i i i N
```

Comment: this works in windows bat/cmd file too

Comment: `banner Hello World` or `figlet Hello World`

Comment: @professorfish The tricky part of this challenge is getting the `,` and `!`.  Otherwise, I'd just use plain old `echo`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma oh, sorry, didn't see that... a bit slow

Answer (score 22):

### base64

```
SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ
```

Satisfies the original rules.

Comment: Is base64 a language? And what's your output? Does it have the correct capitalization?

Comment: Sure it's a language, it's just not Turing-complete. Also, http://base64decode.org

Comment: Haha. For that response, +1 your comment, but not your answer. Maybe your answer later if I feel like it.

Comment: Alternatively you could evaluate the JavaScript expression `atob("SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ")`.

Comment: @Neil you used `"`

Comment: @mniip That was a suggestion to steve as to how to verify the output.

Comment: @KendallFrey By that logic, base10 is a language: 1234567890.

Comment: @Cole — I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Base64 is just a way of encoding numbers. Each "digit" has the range 0-63, just as hexadecimal has the range 0-15 and decimal has the range 0-9. However, each "digit" needs its own representation so they each take up _one_ character. Why? If I were to tell you `132` is base 16, how are you supposed to interpret that? `{1,3,2}` or `{13,2}`. To work around that, we use `a` for `11`, `b` for `12`, and so on. Base 64 works the same way. The "numbers" in base 64 just don't start with `0,1,2,...`.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco My comment was directed towards Kendell Frey's (OP) [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/alphanumeric-hello-world/23003?noredirect=1#comment47516_23003) where he says _"Sure it's [base 64] a language..."_.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Strictly speaking, a *language* (mathematical/cs-theory term) is a set of finite strings formed using characters from a finite alphabet.  Base 64 certainly satisfies this, as does base 10, etc.  A *programming language* is something different. (I know this is a late response, but just for some clarification.)

Answer (score 22):

### Python

So what, we just assume everybody reads horizontally? For those users who like to read vertically:

```
print chr(72) 
print chr(101)
print chr(108)
print chr(108)
print chr(111)
print chr(44)
print chr(32)
print chr(87)
print chr(111)
print chr(114)
print chr(108)
print chr(100)
print chr(33)
```

Comment: +1 and hahaha! This question had so many downvotes at the beginning, because people believed it was impossible. I don't know Python, but given all the moaning I couldn't believe it was THAT easy in such a common language.

Comment: I just wrote the exact same code before this answer was posted. I refreshed to post my answer and found this...

Comment: @steveverrill The moaning wasn't for no reason. There's not a single answer here that would have passed the *original* rules (no braces/parens/brackets, no characters repeated more than once)

Comment: @grovesNL If it makes you feel better, this is the first thing I've *ever* used python for. I spent a while combing through docs, trying to figure out if there was any feasible way to concat them into one line before posting.

Comment: @Geobits `sys.stdout.write` is the standard way to output text without newlines in most versions on Python (the behavior is slightly changed in 3.0). We can't do that here because of the periods.

Comment: @geobits Looks like I got here just in time for the relaxed rules. The only-alphanumeric I saw and knew I could work around. I missed the no-repeats rule.

Answer (score 21):

## Polyglot: HQ9+, H9+, HQ9++, CHIQRSX9+, HQ9+B and HQ9+2D (1 byte)

```
H
```

Thank you @victor for the list of languages.

Comment: This is a polyglot. It works too in H9+, HQ9++, CHIQRSX9+, HQ9+B and HQ9+2D.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it also works in Hello.

Comment: It works in any language that you invent.

Comment: I didn't invented anything...

Comment: Unfortunately the output is "hello, world" (http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B), or according to this interpreter "Hello world." (http://www.almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php)  To get "Hello, world!" you might need to increment the accumulator a few times.

Comment: Necro: Don't forget http://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!

Comment: @RK. I can't use that language since it was made after this challenge was published.

Comment: Yeah, but just for the record :)

Answer (score 21):

### COBOL

```
   ID DIVISION 
   DATA DIVISION 
   01  HELLOWORLDBINARY 
       05  HE                       COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  LL                       COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  OCOMMA                   COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  SPACEW                   COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  ORTEXT                   COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  LD                       COMP    PIC 9999 
       05  EXCLAMATION              COMP    PIC 9999 
   01  FILLER REDEFINES HELLOWORLDBINARY 
       05  HELLOWORLDTEXT                   PIC XXXXXXXXXXXXX
       05  FILLER                           PIC X 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION 
       MOVE 51333                   TO HE 
       MOVE 37779                   TO LL 
       MOVE 38507                   TO OCOMMA 
       MOVE 16614                   TO SPACEW 
       MOVE 38553                   TO ORTEXT 
       MOVE 37764                   TO LD 
       MOVE 23104                   TO EXCLAMATION 
       DISPLAY HELLOWORLDTEXT 
       GOBACK
```

Required some changes to become truly alphanumeric source only.

PROGRAM-ID can be dropped. You get a generated program name (see messages).

WORKING-STORAGE can be dropped. Again the compiler moans.

Since both of these lines previously had missing full-stops/periods, which are no longer relevant now that the descriptions are entirely missing, the number of error messages is the same as before, and still does not affect the generated code for the program.

In changing COMP-5 to COMP, the VALUE clauses are no longer allowed, as COMP 9999 is only four decimal digits whereas COMP-5 is a two-byte binary with all bit-values available.

The values in the MOVEs are the decimal values which give the binary values which give the pairs of characters.

Even though the COMP fields have four digits, and do not allow VALUE clauses with more than four digits, you can use more digits in the MOVE of a literal value without truncation at that point... don't ask me why. Compiler option DIAGTRUNC (which I have turned off) will produce Warning diagnostics for these.

Compiler option TRUNC(BIN) could be used to treat COMP as COMP-5, but the MOVEs are another way to do it.

Since it is COBOL, the output must be in UPPER CASE (a lie, but just for fun).

```
HELLO WORLD!
```

OK, relented, now produces:

```
Hello, World!
```

Which, being an odd-number of characters, required some further changes, since we can't have odd-number-byte binary fields with this compiler. Look at that line of 13 Xs! It would normally be written as X(13), but can be as I've shown...

And ORTEXT is needed (or not OR, anyway) as a name because OR is a reserved word to the compiler (it means OR, of course).

These are EBCDIC values, not ASCII, since it is running on an EBCDIC-aware, and Big Endian, box.

Oh, COBOL requires lots of full-stops/periods. I left them out (they're banned) so got lots of compile messages. Just told the compiler to generate the code anyway (none of the messages relate to the object code).

Even without DIAGTRUNC, the messages are now up to 17...

```
  1  IGYDS1003-E   A "PROGRAM-ID" paragraph was not found. 
  Program-name "CBLNAM01" was assumed. 

  2  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
  before "DATA". 

  3  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
  before "01". 

                   Same message on line:     11 

  3  IGYDS1040-E   A data item was found in the "DATA DIVISION" 
                   before a section header was encountered. 
                   "WORKING-STORAGE SECTION" was assumed. 

  4  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
  before "05". 

                   Same message on line:      5      6      7      8
                   9     10     12     13 

 14  IGYDS1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "PROCEDURE". 

 15  IGYPS2145-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "MOVE". 

 23  IGYSC1082-E   A period was required.  A period was assumed 
 before "END OF PROGRAM".
```

Comment: I don't think `-` is allowed

Comment: Good point. Fixing. Habits.

Comment: @mniip Mmmm.... a little more tricky... I'll have to fix up the WORKING-STORAGE later. I have to leave now...

Comment: I laughed at "Since it is COBOL, the output must be in UPPER CASE".  Nice work!

Answer (score 21):

## OMGROFL

I'm a big fan of esoteric languages. Luckily OMGROFL is alphanumeric:

```
lol iz 72
rofl lol
lol iz 101
rofl lol
lol iz 108
rofl lol
rofl lol
lool iz 111
rofl lool
loool iz 44
rofl loool
loool iz 32
rofl loool
loool iz 87
rofl loool
rofl lool
lool iz 114
rofl lool
rofl lol
lol iz 100
rofl lol
lol iz 33
rofl lol
stfu
```

The `iz` command sets a value to a variable, in this case `lol`, `lool` and `loool` serve as variables...

The `rofl` command echoes out the ASCII equivalent to the number stored in the variable.

The `stfu` command terminates the program ;)

Comment: haha, nice! I wanted to attempt a LOLCODE version but the language requires using a colon and quotation marks to coerce ints to chars.

Answer (score 19):

## Javascript

```
with (function SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ(){}) atob(name)
```

Use browser's console to test.

Comment: Please could you explain how this works? How does `atob(name)` get the name of the function `SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ()`?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33551586/1124350). Since a function is just an object, you can access the `function.name` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Comment: Thanks. because the braces (`{}`) were omitted I mistakenly thought that the function `atob(name)` was outside of the `with()` function

Answer (score 15):

## Ruby (using only alnums and whitespace)

```
putc 72
putc 101
putc 108
putc 108
putc 111
putc 44
putc 32
putc 87
putc 111
putc 114
putc 108
putc 100
putc 33
```

Output: `Hello, World!`

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript

```js
with (String) with ([]) {
    push(fromCharCode(72))
    push(fromCharCode(101))
    push(fromCharCode(108))
    push(fromCharCode(108))
    push(fromCharCode(111))
    push(fromCharCode(44))
    push(fromCharCode(32))
    push(fromCharCode(87))
    push(fromCharCode(111))
    push(fromCharCode(114))
    push(fromCharCode(108))
    push(fromCharCode(100))
    push(fromCharCode(33))
    alert(join([]))
}
```

Comment: ARGH! I hit the same solution, but decided that since it was 2:00 am, I should go to bed and post it in the morning. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 13):

**C**

Uses only alphanumeric characters, spaces and braces {}, brackets [] and parenthesis ().

```
main()
{
        if(printf((long long []){0x202c6f6c6c6548}))
                if(printf((long long []){0x21646c726f57})){}
}
```

printf( ) accepts a char * as an argument, but since we can't use quotes("), I typecast the string as a long long array. The values seen here are ASCII strings, in little endian (0x48=H, 0x65=e, 0x6c=l, and so on). I typecast it to long long [] since that way I can pass an 8-byte argument and hence use only two printf( ) calls instead of four.

Comment: This breaks rule #1

Comment: Chars, numbers, spaces and {} () [] are allowed.

Comment: you can cast an int literal to array? I've never seen this before

Comment: What does this do ?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Array is a pointer. Pointer is an integer.

Comment: @TheRare yes but I've only seen casts such as `(volatile int*)0x12345678` but not casts using `[]` like that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Afaik, the `int[]` is syntactic sugar for `int*`.

Comment: It's not an int literal – note the {}s.

Answer (score 12):

## [ferNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo)

```
h E R
e I S
h E
l L O
w O
r L
d U S
i N G
o N L
y L E
t T E
r S

H e L L o W O R
L d h E L l O w
O r l D h e L L
O w o R l d H E
L l o W o r l d
H E l L o w O R
L D h E L L O W
O r L d H e l l
O w o R l d h e
L l o w O R l D
H e l L o w O R
L d h E L l O W
O R l D H E L l
O w O
r L d
```

Comment: Missing Comma and !

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: works fine over here

Comment: whoops sorry :X

Answer (score 12):

## BBC BASIC

Emulator at bbcbasic.co.uk

Split from my LOGO answer.

**The easy way**

The numbers on the right are just ASCII codes. This is just the same as printing. If I was allowed a comma I could do it on a single line (`VDU 72,101,108,etc.`)

```
   10 VDU 72
   20 VDU 101
   30 VDU 108
   40 VDU 108
   50 VDU 111
   55 VDU 44
   60 VDU 32
   70 VDU 87
   80 VDU 111
   90 VDU 114
  100 VDU 108
  110 VDU 100
  120 VDU 33
```

**A more creative way**

```
    5 MODE 6
   10 READ B
   12 WHILE B
   15   PROC1(B)
   16   PRINT
   17   READ B
   18 ENDWHILE
   20 END

REM procedure prints first square on line, 
REM then calls itself recursively with A DIV 2 to print the next
REM VDU 17 tell VDU controller we want to change colour
REM Next line changes background colour. 
REM Then following line VDU 32 prints a space in that background colour.

  110 DEFPROC1(A)
  115 VDU 17
  120 IF A AND 1 THEN VDU VPOS DIV 6 EOR 133 ELSE VDU 128
  125 VDU 32
  130 IF A THEN PROC1(A DIV2)
  140 ENDPROC

REM binary bitmap data for each row, least significant at left
  150 DATA 463221
  160 DATA 332053
  170 DATA 332151
  180 DATA 332053
  190 DATA 2586485
  200 DATA 1048576
  210 DATA 4395895
  220 DATA 4527447
  230 DATA 4526935
  240 DATA 333143
  250 DATA 4420981
  260 DATA 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

## Rebol

Alphanumeric only solution:

```
prin quote Hello prin add space 12 prin space prin quote World print add space 1
```

Above is an update which uses Dr Rebmu excellent suggestion of `add space 1` (which produces `!`) to get to all the characters.

Below is the original version:

```
prin quote Hello prin pick mold system 264 prin space prin quote World print pick mold system 12
```

Shorter version with brackets:

```
print rejoin [quote Hello pick mold system 264 space quote World pick mold system 12]
```

And even shorter version with braces:

```
print join {Hello} join pick mold system 264 join { World} pick mold system 12
```

And shortest version with both brackets & braces:

```
print rejoin [{Hello} pick mold system 264 { World} pick mold system 12]
```

Rebol uses braces `{}` for multi-line quoting.  So completely valid under rule changes but not quite in full spirit (IMHO) as my first two answers above.

NB. Printing the `!` was a pain!

Rebol allows and uses punctuation characters routinely for function names and datatypes.  So options like `to-char 33` or `to char! 33` would not be allowed under the rules (even though these punctuations are not operators par se).

Fortunately I found a cheeky way by turning the Rebol system object: `make object! [...]` into a string and cherry pick that `!` from it :)

Update: And now also cherry picked comma from license text in system object.

Comment: `!` is not allowed

Comment: @grovesNL - Solution no longer uses `-` or `!` so you may now remove the down vote

Comment: You are missing the comma

Comment: @mniip - Thanks missed that!  Have now fixed.

Comment: Pretty tricky, but you could have just added to space to get the characters... ;-)  [See the Rebmu solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25411/57), which clocks in at 46 chars...

Comment: @Dr.Rebmu - Nice one!  That `add` could come in handy in other golfs.   Have updated.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript!

And they said that it couldn't be done... No assignment operators, no concatenators, no quotes! Arghhhh!

Fear not... For the force is `with` you...

```
function w(x){
    with(document){
        with(String){
            write(fromCharCode(x))
        }
    }
}
w(72)
w(101)
w(108)
w(108)
w(111)
w(44)
w(32)
w(87)
w(111)
w(114)
w(108)
w(100)
w(33)

Output (on browser screen): Hello, World!
```

Comment: He said "Bonus if you can do it in Java" not Javascript.

Comment: @Almo I wasn't aiming to do it in Java... I was focussing on JavaScript, which is my main strength here on this site...

Comment: But you said "And they said that it couldn't be done" which I thought was referring to the puzzle stating bonus for doing it in Java. Many people still confuse Java with Javascript.

Comment: @Almo, I was just using a general saying... And when I refer to "Javascript", I intend to use JavaScript... Trust me, I wasn't planning on going for a bonus...

Answer (score 12):

## DC

DC is just about the perfect tool for the job.

```
5735816763073854918203775149089P
```

DCs `P`-command pops one number from the stack and outputs its raw computer representation to STDIO. Seeing as `5735816763073854918203775149089 = 0x48656C6C6F2C20576F726C6421`, which is represented as `0x21, 0x64, 0x6C... = 'H', 'e', 'l'...` in a little-endian architecture, it outputs `Hello, World!`.

Comment: How does this work? Would you mind adding an explanation?

Comment: Not at all. An explanation will be added shortly.

Comment: +1.  You could do it in hex to save a few chars: `16i48656C6C6F2C20576F726C6421P`

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica

```m
Unprotect[Times]
ClearAll[Times]
Print[Hello FromCharacterCode[44] world FromCharacterCode[33]]
```

Comment: Haha, clever. Very nice!

Comment: Are the square brackets allowed?

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: Isn’t a space missing ?

Answer (score 11):

### Javascript

*Update:* Managed to cut a bunch of characters by introducing a World function as well.

Another Javascript solution that writes to console.log:

```
function World() { with (World) return name }
function Hello() {}
with (console)
with (String)
with (Hello)
with (name)
with (concat(fromCharCode(44)))
with (concat(fromCharCode(32)))
with (concat(World()))
log(concat(fromCharCode(33)))
```

Inspired by [this entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23169/8555).

First, I define functions named Hello and World. This will be used later on.

Then I start my chain of nested withs. The `with (console)` and `with (String)` are used so that I can later on invoke `console.log` and `String.fromCharCode` without using a dot.

The plan is now to build the string `Hello, World!` by abusing nested withs. Each time I invoked concat(), the resulting string will be the context in the next with-block. I take a short cut to quickly get `"Hello"` by accessing the `name` property of the `Hello` function. Then I concatenate the comma and space characters by using `String.fromCharCode`.

The next trick is to get the `"World"` part of the string. I cannot use the same method I used to get `Hello`, since I cannot invoke World.name. Instead I put that logic inside the World method, and invoke it.

Finally, I append the final exclamation mark and send the result right to the log function, which is of course console.log.

Answer (score 10):

## Python:

```
import antigravity
```

causes "Hello, world!" to appear on your screen. Don't believe me? Try it out for yourself!
Also, this doesn't actually use the web, it opens a browser, that might lookup a website.

Comment: I have a 768-pixels height screen, so "Hello, world!" doesn't appear on my screen.

Comment: This does not write "Hello, world!" anywhere in my field of vision. But this opens [*xkcd.com/353/*](http://xkcd.com/353/) in Safari !

Comment: *I am not using the Web now. I am writing in a browser, that might connect to a Web site.*

Comment: http://sciyoshi.com/2008/12/import-antigravity/ The code requires Python 3 to appear but will not run in Python 3 (unless that has been backported).

Answer (score 7):

## Perl

In a modern Perl (5.10 or newer):

```
print q{Hello} and print chr 44 and print q{ World} and say chr 33
```

In older Perl:

```
print q{Hello} and print chr 44 and print q{ World} and print chr 33 and print chr 10
```

Both solutions above use Perl `q` quote-like operator and allows selective delimiters for quoting a string, for eg.  `q{}`  `q[]` `q()`  `q//`

This solution requires the rule change that allows braces, brackets or parens. So while totally valid I think `mniip` excellent Perl answer is more in the true spirit of the rules (+1).

However taking a leaf out of `mniip` answer my solution could be written like so:

```
print q xHellox and print chr 44 and print q x Worldx and say chr 33
```

and while harder on the eye it does work.

Comment: You are missing the comma

Comment: @mniip - Thanks again.  Have now added missing comma.

Comment: Looks like AppleScript without the verbosity

Comment: On my Mac, the first and third Perl lines do not work, only the second Perl line works. I have Perl 5.16.2.

Comment: `syntax error at -e line 1, near "say chr"`

Comment: `Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - Use `perl -E` from command line.  Or if in script add `use 5.010;` (or newer) or `use feature 'say';`.  NB. The "say" statement was added to Perl at version 5.10.

Comment: With `perl -E` and with quotes around the commands, it works. But it does not give the exact string wanted by the question.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - All 3 versions using `perl -E '...code...'` produce `Hello, World!` which is the correct answer.   What do you see?  Please post the exact command line you used to see whats wrong.

Comment: In fact, it does give the correct string now. Sorry, I had confused.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl

```
print chr hex for qw z48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21z
```

Answer (score 5):

## dc, (26 bytes for the golfers)

Whitespace and `[]` brackets are now allowed:

```
[Hello]n44P[ World]n33P[]p
```

Output:

```
$ dc <<< "[Hello]n44P[ World]n33P[]p"
Hello, World!
$
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python:

Pfff, who needs the numeric part of alphanumeric?

```
from string import lowercase
from string import uppercase
from string import punctuation
print uppercase[len(str([[[len(str())]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[]]]]]]]))]
print punctuation[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print
print uppercase[len(str([[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[[[[len(str())]]]]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([[[[[len(str())]]]]]))]
print lowercase[len(str([len(str())]))]
print punctuation[len(str())]
```

This is locale-dependant, so your milage may vary. However, if you really want to replicate this result, you could use the following instead of the import statements:

```
lowercase="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
uppercase="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
punctuation="!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"
```

(this is not part of my submission, it's just sharing my locals for recreatability)

Answer (score 5):

### [Rebmu](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu), 46 characters

```
pnUPPqHELLO01pnADsp12pnSPpnUPPqWORLD01pnADsp01
```

Strongly parallels [@dragetun's solution in Rebol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23054/57)  *(Because Rebmu is a Rebol/Red teaching tool which is a "dialect" that aims to draw attention to the languages by rocking at Code Golf.  :-P)*

However, to get the missing characters, I did something more obvious.  I just added to space, instead of going and looking through system strings.  You can get **add space 1** to get character literal #"!" and **add space 12** to get character literal #",".

If we run this we can see it get "unmushed":

```
>> rebmu/debug/stats "pnUPPqHELLO01pnADsp12pnSPpnUPPqWORLD01prADsp01"
Original Rebmu string was: 46 characters.
Rebmu as mushed Rebol block molds to: 46 characters.
Unmushed Rebmu molds to: 62 characters.
Executing: [pn upp q hello 1 pn ad sp 12 pn sp pn upp q world 1 pr ad sp 1]
Hello, World!
```

Which is fairly logial:

```
; print with no newline the result of doing an uppercase/part
; on the quoting of the symbolic word hello, of only the first
; N characters (where N is 1)
pn upp q hello 1

; print the character you get when you add 12 to the space
; character literal, a.k.a. comma...again no newline
pn ad sp 12

; print a space, no newline
pn sp

; do the same trick of printing the quoted word hello with the
; first letter converted to uppercase
pn upp q world 1

; print the character you get when you add 1 to the space
; character literal, a.k.a. exclamation point...with newline now
pr ad sp 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/)

Okay, we can use whitespace. It uses only `Space`, `Tab`, `LineFeed` and ignores any other characters.

With comment: `S`, `T` or `L` means `Space`, `Tab` or `LineFeed` respectively.

```
S S S T S S T   S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S T   S T L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S S S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   S T T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   T   T   L
T   L
S S S S S T T   T   S S T   S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S T T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T T   S S T   S S L
T   L
S S S S S T S S S S T   L
T   L
S S L
L
L
```

With highlighting: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)#Sample_code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29#Sample_code)

Answer (score 4):

### T-SQL, 52

Ah, this is better! Direct binary conversion, only 52 characters.

```
SELECT CAST(0x48656C6C6F2C20576F726C6421 AS VARCHAR)
```

**Previously...**

There's a much cleverer and golfier solution to this that would work *if* we could use `=` and `+` (Looking up standard built-in data in msdb and using that to construct an EXEC-able query string)

But since we can't, you get this naive approach:

```sql
SELECT CHAR(72)SELECT CHAR(101)SELECT CHAR(108)SELECT CHAR(108)SELECT CHAR(111)SELECT CHAR(44)SELECT CHAR(32)SELECT CHAR(87)SELECT CHAR(111)SELECT CHAR(114)SELECT CHAR(108)SELECT CHAR(100)SELECT CHAR(33)
```

Comment: I know, the lack of concatenation operators is killing me... I'm trying to think of a way to do it with JavaScript...

Comment: Yeah, although this challenge seems to produce mostly naive answers, it has definitely inspired some interesting brain-twisting to try to find interesting non-concatenative approaches.

Comment: You can do better.  Use PRINT rather than SELECT.  And implicitly cast with LTRIM() or RTRIM().  I do something similar [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world/37948#37948).

Answer (score 4):

## Groovy

So updated. Much `wat`.

```
def wat(i) { print i
  this
}
def wat(int i) { wat i as char }
def getProperty(String p) { p }
wat Hello wat 44 wat 32 wat World wat 33
```

Answer (score 4):

## J - 73 char

It *can* be done, after all!

```
72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33{do 1 8{show 0 def 0
take
)
```

Here's the thing about J. [Most of the primitives](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/vocabul.htm) are ASCII punctuation, followed by up to two dots or colons. Those primitives that aren't made of punctuation are an alphanumeric character followed up to two dots or colons. So we're allowed none of those, except for `{ } [ ]`. `[` and `]` are identity verbs and are thus useless.

Luckily, `{` indexes arrays, so if we had, say, a string with every single ASCII character ([`a.`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dadot.htm), called *Alphabet*), we could pull the letters out by their ASCII codepoints. We also have [a backup way of making strings](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm), `0 : 0` and then stuff and then a lone `)`; the colon in which has an alias in the standard library, [`def`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_stdlib.htm#def).

Then there's a verb in the standard library, [`show`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_jade.htm#show), that gives you the internal representation of a verb if you pass it the name as a string. There's another verb, [`do`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_stdlib.htm#do), that will eval a string. So if we can pull out an `a.` from any such representation, we can eval that and pull out `Hello, World!`.

Our saviour comes in the form of [`take`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_stdlib.htm#take), an alias for `{.` that has an `a` in its name. `show'take'` will return `take=: {.`, so we have our `a.` and thus a solution.

We can get rid of `{` by using the essentially equivalent [`pick`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_stdlib.htm#pick) from the standard library, but the paren at the very end can't be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

## perl

How about a more straight-forward perl implentation?

```
print q zHelloz and print chr 44 and print q z worldz and print chr 33
```

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript

```
389960998265612367812323333 115base]zip
```

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Mzg5OTYwOTk4MjY1NjEyMzY3ODEyMzIzMzMzIDExNWJhc2Vdemlw)

#### How it works

Since both number and square brackets are allowed, pushing an array containing the character codes of all bytes in the string “Hello, World!” is straightforward:

```
[72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33]
```

The highest character count is 114, so we could also push this array as a base 115 number:

```
389960998265612367812323333 115base
```

The problem lays in casting this array to a string. There's already a string on the stack (the empty string, since there was no input from STDIN). Strings have higher priority than arrays in GolfScript, so any way of combining the empty string with the array from above will yield a string.

Almost all built-ins are out, since they use non-alphanumeric characters (e.g., `+` for concatenation), but we can use `zip`, which transposes array rows with columns.

First, we append a `]` to the array, so a two-dimensional array consisting of the empty string an the character array will lay on the stack.

Then, we append `zip`. The result of the transpose will be the following array:

```
[   "H"   "e"   "l"   "l"   "o"   ","   " "   "W"   "o"   "r"   "l"   "d"   "!"   ]
```

By default, GolfScript prints all item on the stack, one by one. The result is:

```
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 3):

## GO (golang)

```go
package main

func main() {
    print(string(72))
    print(string(101))
    print(string(108))
    print(string(108))
    print(string(111))
    print(string(44))
    print(string(32))
    print(string(87))
    print(string(111))
    print(string(114))
    print(string(108))
    print(string(100))
    print(string(33))
}
```

No "fmt" used... Just print.

Answer (score 3):

### Lua (112)

```
io[ [[write]]][[Hello]]io[ [[write]]](string[ [[char]]](44))io[ [[write]]][[ World]]print(string[ [[char]]](33))
```

Pretty straightforward. Lua's alternate string syntax is quite a boon here, in addition to "the only data structure is a table" which means that `io.write` is equilavent to `io['write']`.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell

Not exactly a program, as it is impossible to create a program without `main=`.
This is simply an expression for an interactive interpreter, such as `ghci`:

```
putStrLn (map toEnum (scanl (const id) 72 (scanl (const id) 101 (scanl (const id) 108 (scanl (const id) 111 (scanl (const id) 44 (scanl (const id) 32 (scanl (const id) 119 (scanl (const id) 111 (scanl (const id) 114 (scanl (const id) 108 (scanl (const id) 100 [33]))))))))))))
```

`scanl (const id)` is used instead of `(:)`,
`toEnum :: a -> Char` is used instead of `chr`, as I'd have to import `Data.Char` then.

Answer (score 2):

### Emacs Lisp

Displays "Hello, World!" in a browser when you eval it.

it's lisp as ascii values of base64  of lisp of base64 of ascii values if you start unobfuscating it.

```
(eval (read (eval (list (intern (string 98 97 115 101 54 52 45 100 101 99 111 100 101 45 115 116 114 105 110 103))
                        (string 75 71 120 108 100 67 65 111 75 71 90 112 98 71 85 103 75 71 86 50 89 87 119 103
                                75 72 74 108 89 87 81 103 75 71 74 104 99 50 85 50 78 67 49 107 90 87 78 118 90
                                71 85 116 99 51 82 121 97 87 53 110 73 67 74 76 83 69 52 119 89 50 49 115 100 86
                                112 53 10 81 84 86 78 97 85 70 52 84 85 82 82 90 48 49 85 81 88 104 74 82 69 86
                                51 84 48 78 66 101 69 49 69 90 50 100 78 86 69 86 52 83 85 82 70 101 69 57 84 81
                                88 104 78 86 69 86 110 84 86 82 70 77 69 108 69 82 88 100 80 81 48 70 52 84 85 82
                                66 10 90 48 49 85 82 88 104 74 82 69 86 52 84 110 108 66 101 69 49 85 87 87 100
                                78 86 69 86 53 83 85 82 70 101 69 53 53 81 88 104 78 86 70 108 110 84 107 82 90
                                90 48 49 85 81 84 66 74 82 69 86 52 84 109 108 66 101 69 49 69 97 50 100 78 86 69
                                69 48 10 83 49 69 57 80 83 73 112 75 83 107 112 75 83 65 111 100 50 108 48 97 67
                                49 48 90 87 49 119 76 87 90 112 98 71 85 103 90 109 108 115 90 83 65 111 97 87 53
                                122 90 88 74 48 73 67 104 108 100 109 70 115 73 67 104 121 90 87 70 107 73 67 104
                                105 89 88 78 108 10 78 106 81 116 90 71 86 106 98 50 82 108 76 88 78 48 99 109 108
                                117 90 121 65 105 83 48 104 79 77 71 78 116 98 72 86 97 101 85 69 121 84 85 78 66
                                101 69 49 69 85 87 100 79 86 69 86 110 84 109 112 74 90 48 53 54 83 87 100 78 86 69
                                70 52 83 85 82 70 10 100 48 57 68 81 88 104 78 82 71 100 110 84 86 82 70 101 69 108
                                69 85 84 66 74 82 69 49 53 83 85 82 110 77 48 108 69 82 88 104 78 85 48 70 52 84 86
                                82 82 90 48 49 85 81 84 82 74 82 69 86 51 84 85 78 66 101 107 49 53 81 84 74 78 81
                                48 69 119 10 84 110 108 66 101 69 49 69 85 87 100 79 86 69 86 110 84 109 112 74 99
                                67 73 112 75 83 107 112 75 83 65 111 89 110 74 118 100 51 78 108 76 88 86 121 98 67
                                49 118 90 105 49 109 97 87 120 108 73 71 90 112 98 71 85 112 73 67 107 103)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## CJam

One of the few answers satisfying the original requirement for the character set:

```
72c101c108c108c111c44c32c87c111c114c108c100c33c
```

This straightforwardly builds the string character by character.

Another solution:

```
389960998265612367812323333 115b{Xc}fX
```

This converts the first number to base 115 then converts each digit to a character.

And finally, a solution that uses only 3 different characters: K, ) and c (newlines are optional):

```
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))c
K)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))c
K)))))))))))))c
```

I used K because it's the variable initialized with the largest number (20).

Online interpreter: http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Answer (score 1):

## FORTH

UPDATE:
Here's the basically similar version that executed straight from forth file, as opposed to defining a WORD (subroutine) and it uses only alphanumeric characters.

```
72 EMIT
101 EMIT
108 EMIT
108 EMIT
111 EMIT
44 EMIT
32 EMIT
87 EMIT
111 EMIT
114 EMIT
108 EMIT
100 EMIT
33 EMIT
```

been a while with FORTH but this seems to work, thanks for the 'C' language reply I didn't bother looking up ACSII codes.
I used the iMop and iBucket (http://sourceforge.net/projects/powermops/files/iMops/)
and also tested with an osx variant (https://sites.google.com/site/chrishinsley/)

```
: HELLOWORLD ( -- )
72 EMIT
101 EMIT
108 EMIT
108 EMIT
111 EMIT
44 EMIT
32 EMIT
87 EMIT
111 EMIT
114 EMIT
108 EMIT
100 EMIT
33 EMIT
;
```

code: 224     data: 16

cr HELLOWORLD

Hello, World!

Comment: I don't think `:`, `-`, or `;` are allowed.  Otherwise, nice post.

Comment: the colon, dash, and semi-colon are language basic delimiters.  although there might be some way to type it in the interpreter without defining a WORD (which is Forth for subroutine).  maybe I'll try APL next.  :-0

Comment: Yeah, I know.  This challenge is a tough one to start on.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 148 bytes

```python
from binascii import unhexlify
print unhexlify(bytearray(str(0)if c in hex(14)else c for c in hex(0x48656c6c6f2c2e776f726c6421)if c not in hex(0L)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**REXX**

Using standard build-in functions only (ASCII based)

```
  SAY x2c(48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421)
```

Yields:

> Hello, World!

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 46 bytes (with invalid underscore)

```
if(print(base64_decode(SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ))){}
```

### PHP - 88 bytes

```
if(print(Hello))if(print(chr(44)))if(print(chr(32)))if(print(World))if(print(chr(33))){}
```

Works by abusing the fact that PHP will assume any unassigned constant is a string equal to its name.

Comment: Underscore is not allowed

Comment: So second nature I hadn't even realised. Luckily, I had an alternate.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket

```
(quasiquote (unquote (quote (Hello (unquote (quote World))))))
```

It barely works. The output is `'(Hello ,'world)`

To run this code, start DrRacket and paste the code above to the console.

Don't do it in Advanced Student Language, it shows up `(list 'Hello (list 'unquote (list 'quote 'world)))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
with(String) {
    with(console) {
        log(fromCharCode(72))
        log(fromCharCode(101))
        log(fromCharCode(108))
        log(fromCharCode(108))
        log(fromCharCode(111))
        log(fromCharCode(44))
        log(fromCharCode(32))
        log(fromCharCode(87))
        log(fromCharCode(111))
        log(fromCharCode(114))
        log(fromCharCode(108))
        log(fromCharCode(100))
        log(fromCharCode(33))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Firefox console displays this as

> H
>   e
>   l(2)
>   o

etc....

Comment: I managed to find a way of displaying it on the browser screen... see my answer below: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23169/8555

Answer (score 0):

## Java (NetBeans)

```
class Hello extends Exception
{
    Hello(String s)
    {
        super(s)
    }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Hello
    {
        world((char)130)
    }
    
    static void world(char c) throws Hello
    {
        throw new Hello(new String(new char[]{c}))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" Hello: ,
    at HelloWorld.world(HelloWorld.java:18)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:13)
Java Result: 1
```

A few notes:

1. NetBeans allows you to omit semicolons, but isn't happy about it. Eclipse and `javac` don't compile.
2. I don't get the +10 brownie points, since including unnecessary output is bending (but not violating) the rules.
3. The exclamation point is courtesy of NetBeans, objecting like crazy to the lack of semicolons.

Comment: I get `Hello.java:12: error: ';' expected super(s)` from the compiler.

Comment: @Riking What IDE are you using?

Comment: That was with `javac`. Eclipse gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements` when you try to run it.

Comment: Okay; I guess it's compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

### Lua

```
io[ [[write]]][[Hello]]
io[ [[write]]](string[ [[char]]](44))
io[ [[write]]][[ World]]
io[ [[write]]](string[ [[char]]](33))
```

**edit:** Didn't see AlliedEnvy's answer, which is identical to mine, except mine doesn't print a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA

Since equals, quotes and dot are out of the question, and as everyone loves message boxes:

```
Sub helloworld()
    MsgBox Chr(72)
    MsgBox Chr(101)
    MsgBox Chr(108)
    MsgBox Chr(108)
    MsgBox Chr(111)
    MsgBox Chr(44)
    MsgBox Chr(87)
    MsgBox Chr(111)
    MsgBox Chr(114)
    MsgBox Chr(108)
    MsgBox Chr(100)
    MsgBox Chr(33)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (111 chars)

```
<?=chr(72).chr(101).chr(108).chr(108).chr(111).chr(44).chr(32).chr(87).chr(111).chr(114).chr(108).chr(100).chr(33)?>
```

Assuming `.` is OK (I have used: `[chr0-9\(\)\.]`).

Answer (score 0):

## dc - 25 bytes

```
33[ World]44[Hello]PaPPap
```

I'm starting to like dc.

Answer (score 0):

### Logo, 52 chars

```
pr se word [Hello] char 44 word char [World] char 33
```

Using the new rule that brackets are allowed. Otherwise, one could `word` together lots more `char`s to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia

Option 1, using square brackets and join, and just one print/char:

```
print(join(char([72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33])))
```

Option 2, one "char" at a time:

```
print(char(72))
print(char(101))
print(char(108))
print(char(108)
print(char(111))
print(char(44))
print(char(32))
print(char(87))
print(char(111))
print(char(114))
print(char(108))
print(char(100))
print(char(33))
```

Options 3 + 4, same as above, but with 0x?? char creation. That is, rather than char(72), use 0x72. Or, in the join case, replace 72 with 0x72 (and so on) and remove the "char" operation entirely.

Answer (score -2):

### Common Lisp

This almost works, except that `-` isn't allowed.  If only there were the functions `stringCapitalize` and `codeChar` instead…

```
(mapcar (lambda (x)
          (princ (string-capitalize x)))
        (list (quote hello)
              (code-char 44)
              (code-char 32)
              (quote world)
              (code-char 33))))
```

The nice thing here is that string-capitalize takes a *string designator*, which can be a string, symbol, or character.  Sample use:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar (lambda (x)
                   (princ (string-capitalize x)))
                 (list (quote hello)
                       (code-char 44)
                       (code-char 32)
                       (quote world)
                       (code-char 33)))
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `-` is banned.

Comment: @Geobits aww… I got excited when I saw that parens were allowed… I think I can work around this, though