# What did we forget?

Tags: code-golf, source-layout, radiation-hardening

Your task is to write a non-empty computer program comprised of some sequence of bytes.  If we choose a particular byte in the program and remove all instances of it from the program, the modified program should output the removed byte.

For example if our program were

```
aabacba
```

Then `bcb` would output `a`, `aaaca` would need to output `b` and `aababa` would output `c`.

It does not matter what the unmodified program does.

Answers will be scored in bytes with the goal being to minimize the number of bytes.

Comment: Since this challenge isn't tagged quine, may we read our own source code?

Comment: @Dennis Sure. Be my guest

Comment: If all the bytes in our program  represent digits, may we output via exit code?

Comment: I think this would be better as a code challenge where you have to maximise the number of discrete characters used.

Comment: @tsh that’d be pretty interesting!

Comment: Should've specified *more than 1 byte* instead of *non-empty* :P. Or what Notts90 said.

Comment: @Notts90 Probably. The radiation hardening already makes the non-trivial answers quite hard.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The votes agree with you... this is a case of code-golf with the 548 byte answer getting the lion's share of upvotes!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn More than 1 byte would mean that all the one byte answers would just be two bytes, e.g. `11` for retina.  Unless you mean more than one *distinct* byte.  Which would probably have improved the challenge.

Comment: Is output with a trailing newline acceptable? (If so, would the output when the newline character is removed have to be two newlines?)

Comment: There is no clear meta consensus on this, and in any case whether two newlines would be required if a newline was removed is a challenge-specific question (as it essentially amounts to "is it okay to only *sometimes* add a trailing newline).

Comment: @Doorknob Ok you can add an extra new line.

Comment: Would the output when a newline is removed have to be two newlines, then, or would a single newline be acceptable (when all other outputs have trailing newlines)?

Comment: @Doorknob It should probably be 2.

Answer (score 73):

### zsh, <s>603</s> <s>594</s> <s>566</s> <s>561</s> <s>548</s> <s>440</s> <s>415</s> <s>399</s> <s>378</s> 370 bytes

```sh
ec
ho \\n;ca t<<<$'\x20';exi t
d$c -e8BC6P
d0c -eKp
$'\172\163\150' $'\055\143' $'\146\157\162 v \151\156 \173\043\056\056\134\175\175\073\173 \146\147\162\145\160 \055\161 $\166 '$0$'\174\174\074\074\074$\166\073\175'
$'\145v\141\154' $':\073\072\046\046\145\170\151\164';#%&()*+,/9=>?@ADEFGHIJLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`jklmsuwy
0# $#;for b in {$..z};{ fgrep -q $b $0||<<<$b;}
```

Depends on coreutils + `dc`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFpc9MwFPyuX7GTiIgrjpzIDmDXLZSj3PdZF0hsuUlJ5dR2g0ma3x6eFShoZp9W2nfsSMtysklGFaLxqNTOspwgDIXOM7HRCZvkiGMTJCNUYRhyEdd9KQJdT1GxlCfo6lv39v1XLJUNfzpnlOIO@7HrD2LXkwJ0lp4Xu2pguat8uh@S3scCRF2CT2Q4iKUieL6FO1B051lI0kjHtljZYtpJ9CW23X0XnKIPwaV1oCzkP1j5TytPWJvKW1BoDKjG2x2rSjIvaY60sxoDcuvSVyJoX@lcvXb9xs3e7Z1od@/u/QcPHx08fvLs@YuXr9@8fff@w8dPn78cHn399v3kx@y0PP/5i8k2eDvI8gJjTA1W3HGW62CF7LjQc3TPwMfg8uKiedxxsN7QuzPWpNdNuoiNwEpAOI5YizVLcwZaOqFv6Rq0Cn2aL6bmGIe8PsJOhJbVqwLdFC1etxBefmpU6bJqmE1Jp1mGS@2vhKiX6kXPnM9m6HS2c4TJK8wLXWpTNZ6SPNXC9vi/kqwZvfkN)

That was... a journey.

This answer has three parts. The first 4 lines handle certain special cases to simplify the code that follows. The next 2 lines and the last line both accomplish essentially the same thing, but exactly one is run with any given character removal. They are written with mostly complementary character sets, so that removing any character breaks only one at most, allowing the other to continue to function.

Looking at the first part, we first handle

- newline removal with `ec\nho \\n`
- space removal with `ca t<<<$'\x20'` (followed by `exi t` to avoid running later code, which would result in extraneous output)
- `$` removal with `d$c -e8BC6P` (`8BC6` = `9226` is `36*256 + 10`, and 36 and 10 are the byte values of the `$` and newline characters respectively; we use hex digits in decimal to avoid having to include them in the large comment in line 6)
- `0` removal with `d0c -eKp` (`K` gets the decimal precision, which is `0` by default)

In the next part, the only characters used (aside from the garbage at the end of the second line) are `$'\01234567v;`, space, and newline. Of these, four have been accounted for, so the remainder (`'\1234567v`) cannot occur in the last line. Expanding the octal escapes (`$'\123'` represents the ASCII character with value 123<sub>8</sub>), we get:

```sh
zsh -c 'for v in {#..\}};{ fgrep -q $v '$0'||<<<$v;}'
eval ':;:&&exit'
```

The first line loops through all characters used in the program and searches for each one in its own source code (`$0` is the filename of the script being run), printing any character that is not found.

The second line looks a little strange, and appears to do the same thing as `exit` with a bunch of nops. However, encoding `exit` as octal directly results in `$'\145\170\151\164'`, which does not contain `2` or `3`. We actually need to make this *less* resilient to removals. This is because if any of `'\014567v` are removed, breaking the first line, the second line also breaks, allowing the remainder of the code to execute. However, we need it to also break if `2` or `3` are removed so that lines 3 and 4 can run. This is accomplished by shoehorning in `:` and `;`, which have a 2 and 3 in their octal representation respectively.

The junk at the end of line 2 is simply there to ensure every printable ASCII character appears at least once, as the way the checking is done by looping through each one requires this.

If `exit` was not called in the first section (i.e. it was mangled by the removal of one of `'\01234567v`), we move on to the second, in which we must accomplish the same thing without using any of these characters. The last line is similar to the decoded first line, except that we can contract the range of the loop to save a few bytes, because we already know that all characters except for `'\01234567v` have been covered. It also has `0# $#` before it, which comments it out and prevents it from producing extraneous output if `0` or `$` were removed.

Comment: Wow, very impressive considering the amount of distinct characters involved! Definitely looking forward seeing that explanation.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen here you go :)

Comment: @Doorknob if this doesn't win you 548 internets, I don't know what does. Honestly, the 603 byte version is just as impressive hah!

Comment: The only interesting answer so far.

Answer (score 22):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 1 byte

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/H4gA)

When all instances of the single byte (`1`) are removed, the output is `1`. Simple enough.

Comment: I was browsing TIO to find something like this - you beat me to it. Btw this is a polyglot, works with Snails

Comment: IMO, this answer should be upgraded to a polyglot answer as the first one (possibly with a forever-incomplete list of languages), and the other two downvoted to oblivion. Oh, and this also [works in ***C***](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint).

Comment: @Rogem I'm not sure what you mean by "this works in C." do you have a C compiler which outputs `1` for the empty program? Regardless, I think the answers in question utilize different approaches and behaviours. IMO a polyglot answer is only warranted if the approach remains the same. (Objectively, this isn't a polyglot as the actual code is different, for the answers below.) Feel free to vote how you want, but a valid answer is a valid answer. I will keep my answer as it is, I don't wish to house a collection of answers on it.

Answer (score 12):

### Lenguage, 216173027061157310 bytes

`216173027061157310 = (144115617572598740 + 144115241762960340 + 144115194786755540) / 2`. There are `216173027061157310 - 144115617572598740` `$`s, `216173027061157310 - 144115241762960340` `#`s and `216173027061157310 - 144115194786755540` spaces.

The 144115617572598740 `#`s and spaces encode the following BF program:

```
++++++[>++++++<-]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwyi7SC0jW6snd7//wA)

The 144115241762960340 `$`s and spaces encode the following BF program:

```
+++++++[>+++++<-]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKi7cCUjW6snd7//wA)

The 144115194786755540 `$`s and `#`s encode the following BF program:

```
++++++++[>++++<-]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwqi7UCkjW6snd7//wA)

Edit: Saved 72057832274401770 bytes thanks to @Nitrodon.

Comment: Why not use `U` and byte 127? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20ZXVzfWTo/LjksXygXy/v8HAA "brainfuck – Try It Online") Or even just the nul byte and soh?

Comment: @JoKing I didn't know that `U` was the shortest printable ASCII byte that could be output. I didn't want to use unprintable bytes.

Comment: Even without taking advantage of wrapping cells or unprintable characters, you can get this down to 216173027061157310 bytes by including the space character as a third distinct byte.

Comment: I can't help but upvote because of "Edit: Saved 72057832274401770 bytes..."

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
0
```

Completely different from the Retina answer. *whistles*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g/38A)

Comment: Polyglot with M and Enlist.

Answer (score 9):

## Polyglot<sup>*</sup>, 1 byte ([awaiting confirmation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171789))

```
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/3@D/fwA) (using Triangularity)

*: This works in a (rather wide) variety of languages (except for esolangs like 4, ><> and the like and some other exceptions). Identical to [the Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171797/59487) in source code, but the method of I/O is different – Output is via exit code. When one removes `0` from the source code, they're left with an empty program, which often doesn't error and yields exit code **0** in the majority of languages.

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/n@v/fwA)

Completely different from the Retina answer, or the Jelly answer.

Comment: I don't see any code. Wouldn't that make it a 0 byte answer? How does this work?

Comment: @Mast There is a newline..... you will have difficulty reading [programs written in Whitespace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27072/69850) if you keep thinking like that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) (non-competitive), 96 bytes

```
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101  ................
```

Here is [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) dump.

A wider definition of Unary language allows any characters in its source code. But I havn't find a compiler or interpreter which would work for this. So I marked this answer as non-competitive. If you can find one which posted before this question asked, I will link to it.

Comment: This is the smallest Unary program I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 143 bytes

```
<\Hs+:+:PPPs\
\sM:+:+H
HP+:+:PPPs++\
HsssssssM+++\
;HssssMMMMM++\
;o+:+:PPs++\
+:+:P+:PPP\H+P:P+:
ssssMMMMMM\H
sHsssMMMMM+\
Hsssss+++\
HMMMMMMs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCcAwDEPvXsUbtB1AF4MH8LkfKOSg/XEbh0QnSTzpau/58M48AtRNN3dnSNB@rxD4LFVDwCHTnvaK1lWxDbTIsjUMqHcrC7aAEGs6b@sTg2DmBw)

This contains the characters `<\Hs+:PM;o` and newline

- `<` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7CQAxDEN7r@INcguoMXgA1/eBgxTaH9/FIVEliSdd/T0f3pkBatPm7gwJ2u8VAl@lagg4ZTrSUdGGKvaJFlm2hgH1YWXDFhBiT9dtfWISzPwA)
- `\` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLDcAwCEPvrMIGaQfwBYkp@pEq5eD9RUNo45Mf2D77c9y8InZQmzZ3p9CGUwj8P6kKWDIdsE2yVFKvXMammyWop5OVNAixat9grqHejHgB)
- `H` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLDcAwCEPvrOIN0q4QiQE49yNVysH7ixRQWp@ejfE5nuPm5b4b0dBUlSbG/jJEVwSYsNQRZksMpRtVzF5ivhk0SL5ut5/XYs7Vle4T)
- `s` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7DcBACEN7VvEGlwzgBokBqPORIl2R/UUOiBueAL9zPsf9XhG7EwPDzFxcF4FC@1eACxU5NmqmcPY5uajrhCVK/akvTTeWAi2qRHw)
- `+` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9DoBQCIN3joQegIWEA3T2JzF5Q@8fBF/ULgX6lX1c28kjc4VRNSIIAV3VxOI9GKccsjyzt2oZTRRQ1iiqEiof4TCh/fz8Uz5TZt4)
- `:` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7DQAxCEN7VmGEuwHcRGIA6vtIJ6Xw/iKE6OICYXj23b/r5RNxOqhqZnRxNlUIbB1UXcClfKQ7yrapsn2CxeUyM46cKptqDiF25u@rMiyCEQM)
- `P` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLDcAwDELvXoUN0g7AxRv43I9UKQf2l9s4ajgBenD257h1Ze5BoaEpLOSfAY1VAGHUlGOkraIPVeyLGwYtamgL8qCJa/Lf1RcnocwX)
- `M` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7DcBADEJ7r8IGlwxA6QFc5yNFusL7yznbSqgeCDjnc9x@RexGx8BQVTcxXwgK9csAE3oLaTY2LppdKlNYEyM0UbJnFM/B/4I@jHgB)
- `;` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYy7CQAxDEN7r@INwg2gxuABXN8HDlJof3yXmESVJJ509fd8eGceAWrT5u4MCdrvFQJfpWoIWDLdyYZG6gVObto5C6gPK5u1gBB7uU7rsQhmfg)
- `o` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCcAwDEPvXkUbpB1AF4MH8LkfKPTg/XEbh0QnSTzpfJ/jjitzdwYampmFi4f@HhTaLAEXxpCip62idlUcZIFla@eEdSuLVacE13K@1iUHEZkf)
- Newline [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUy5DcAwCBzoNnAyAA0SA1DnkSK5YH8RnsRX3X/O57jtct@VDANDREzVOCiI5LeAyBuMEFspTqSa3ctasRopQZKuJscHrdl3mG/Usbm/)

I wanted to solve this in a 2D language, but most 2D languages are ruled out from this challenge. Gol><> works because of the large number of operations including operations with overlapping functionality, this ensures that we can write a meaningful program with any 1 character banned.

We use the standard [radiation-hardening](/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening) technique for 2D languages here.  The removal of characters causes the length of a line to change which creates a new alignment and sends the pointer down a new path untouched by the radiation.

Each character gets its own line of the program and which line is run is triggered by the removal.  We could possibly choose a smaller character set to work with `<\Ho;P1+` and newline should work, however the lines would be very long making this overall more costly.